# How to store values indexed by integer partitions for fast access?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge list of values indexed by integer partitions. If I store them simply in a list, then, when I want to access the value corresponding to some particular integer partition, I have to find the index of the given partition in the list of all partitions before I can access the value. This is slow. Is there a way to optimize this?

In my particular example, I have values indexed by pairs of partitions of the same integers. The first 4 levels look like this:

```
chars = {
  {{1}}, 
  {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, 2}, {1, -1, 1}}, 
  {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1, 1, 3}, {0, -1, 2, 0, 2}, {1, 0, -1, -1, 3}, 
   {-1, 1, 1, -1, 1}}
}
```

Then to access a particular value, I use this function:

```
maxn = 4;
YDs = Array[IntegerPartitions[#] &, maxn];

findChar[y1_, y2_] := Module[{l1, l2, n1, n2, i1, j1},
  l1 = Length[y1];
  l2 = Length[y2];
  n1 = Sum[y1[[i]], {i, l1}];
  n2 = Sum[y2[[i]], {i, l2}];
  If[n1 != n2, Return["ERROR"];];
  i1 = Position[YDs[[n1]], y1, Heads -> False][[1, 1]];
  j1 = Position[YDs[[n2]], y2, Heads -> False][[1, 1]];
  Return[chars[[n1, i1, j1]]];
];
```

This seems to be a pretty inefficient way, but I don't know how to do it more effectively in Mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematica.stackexchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). It would be extremely helpful if you would provide a *small working* example of what you try to achieve. What is `maxn` in your code? Can you edit your question and fix this?

Comment: In this case maxn=4, I've edited the question to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Create a dispatch table of indexes.**  To illustrate, let's make over a million integer partitions to work with:

```
y = Flatten[Array[IntegerPartitions, 50], 1]; Length[y]
```

> $1295970$

Associate each with an index via a `Rule` and optimize the subsequent rule replacements with a dispatch table:

```
table = Dispatch[Rule @@@ Transpose[{y, Range@Length@y}]];
```

(This precomputation takes $2.8$ seconds here.)  To test its use, let's work out the indexes for a million randomly selected integer partitions:

```
x = RandomChoice[y, 10^6]; First@AbsoluteTiming@(x /. table)
```

> $1.7851021$

In other words, it takes less than two microseconds on average to look up the index for any of these partitions.  I hope this is fast enough for the intended application.

Comment: By just quickly hacking this solution into my code, I obtained a 2- to 10-fold increase in speed in my functions that work with these kinds of lists.