# Accessing list elements by name

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, programming, chemistry

First, a bit of a long introduction to my problem:

I only have a few weeks of Mathematica experience.  I am creating a mathematica application that calculates some material properties of steel based on metallurgical functions that include multiple chemical elements.  I currently have the chemistry stored in a vector, and the list of elements stored in a second vector of the same length.  Here's an example:

```
elements={"C","Mn","S","P","Si","Cu","Ni","Cr","V","Cb","Mo","Sn","Al","Ca","B","Ti","N","O","Ce","Pb","Bi","W","As","Zn","Sb"};
chemistry={0.032`,1.2`,0.0259`,0.006`,0.04`,0.15`,0.06`,0.04`,0.001`,0.051`,0.167`,0.007`,0.035`,0.0001`,0.`,0.001`,0.0087`,0.0176`,0.0002`,0.0001`,0.`,0.`,0.004`,0.036`,0.`};
```

I created a function called *elem* to look up the element name in *elements*, and find the corresponding entry in *chemistry* (or any other chemistry list of proper format):

```
elem[chem_,element_] := chem[[Flatten[Position[elements,element]]]][[1]];
```

For example, if I want to look up Nickel ("Ni") from the *chemistry* list, I use the following to get 0.06:

```
elem[chemistry, "Ni"]
```

The neat thing about this is when you write a formula using the elem function, the list *elements* can be used to print the formula in a more user-friendly way for verification.  For example, the Titanium to Nitrogen ratio is one of the simpler formulas of interest:

```
TiByN[chem_] := elem[chem, "Ti"]/elem[chem,"N"]
```

When called with *chemistry*, it returns a number (0.114943), but when you call *TiByN* with *elements*, it returns the formula **Ti/N**.  This way, I can print a list of formulas in a format that the metallurgists can read when they audit my application.

**My question is one of performance.**  I need to do an optimization involving these formulas, and I think this method of indexing the chemistry is one of my big bottlenecks.  Is there any way to precompile a function like *elem* for the list *elements* so that the position doesn't have to be looked up for every element in every formula on every iteration of the optimization?

Thanks

Comment: see "Functions That Remember Values They Have Found" in the manual

Comment: This thread is very closely related--the principal (only?) difference is that other objects ("integer partitions") are the arguments rather than strings--http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22309/how-to-store-values-indexed-by-integer-partitions-for-fast-access.

Comment: As you mentioned that you are relatively new to Mathematica I wonder whether you have any indication that more common ways to handle this won't do? One straightforward way is (close to Istvans answer): define your formulas e.g. as `TiByN="Ti"/"N"` and then  insert numeric values with something like `TiByN /. parameters` where `parameters = Thread[elements->chemistry]` (you could use `Dispatch` for optimization). With such an approach you can very easily control whether and when to insert values. What you do looks a little like working against the (strong parts of the) system to me...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Simple version using a variant of memoization

While part of the answer I was going to give was already posted by Istvan, I will still post mine since the self-precomputing part was not part of Istvan's answer. The following will use the variant of memoization to precompute the dispatch table:

```
ClearAll[elem];
elem[chem_, element_] :=
  With[{dispatchTable = Dispatch[Thread[ elements -> chem]]},
    elem[chem, el_] := el /. dispatchTable;
    elem[chem, element]];
```

What happens here is that the general new definition is created upon the first call with a given property, and then that more specific definition is used:

```
elem[chemistry, "C"]

(*  0.032  *)
```

#### Making a function generator

One flaw of the above answer is that the function `elem` depends on a global variable `elements`, in a rather non-transparent way. A better way would be to make a function generator:

```
ClearAll[makeElem];
makeElem[elemName_Symbol, elements_] :=
  elemName[chem_, element_] :=
    With[{dispatchTable = Dispatch[Thread[ elements -> chem]]},
      elemName[chem, el_] := el /. dispatchTable;
      elemName[chem, element]];
```

In this case, everything is local. One can now generate the `elem` function as

```
Clear[elem];
makeElem[elem, elements]
```

and then use it as before:

```
elem[chemistry, "C"]

(*  0.032  *)
```

#### Making this object-oriented

While the function generator is a better answer than the simple version, it may have a problem in that you have to come up with a name of the function `elem` - while this function is intimately tied with the particular set of elements. This calls for an OO approach, where it will be encapsulated in an instance (object), which will be created from a given list of elements. Here I will show how one can do this using an [object-oriented extension](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/once-more-on-object-orientation-in-mathematica-does-it-have-to-be-so-hard/16870#16870) I have proposed some time ago.

First, to try it, you have to execute

```
Import["https://gist.github.com/lshifr/4266126/raw/OO.m"]
```

which will load the OO package. Here is then a possible way to do what we want:

```
DeclareType[ChemicalElement][
   OO`Methods`new[elements_List] :=
     Module[{elem},
        $self@AddMethods[
          OO`Methods`addProperty[prop_] :=
             Module[{dispatchTable = Dispatch[Thread[ elements -> prop]]},
                $self@AddMethods[
                   OO`Methods`get[prop, el_] := el /. dispatchTable
                ]
             ]
        ];
        $self
     ]
];
```

It is perhaps a bit more complex than it needs be, since some of the mechanisms of the current `` OO` `` implementation are not perfect. What is done here is that I declared a type `ChemicalElement` with a `new` method. This method, when called, constructs an instance of `ChemicalElement` type and adds a new method `addProperty` (this is possible because the object model of `` OO` `` is flexible enough to be able to add methods on per-instance basis at run-time - which is e.g. not possible in Java but possible in Javascript).

Whenever you want to add a new property to your object, you call `addProperty`. So, here is our example:

```
ch = ChemicalElement[{}] @ new[elements]

(* « ChemicalElement[]» *)
```

Now we add the property `chemistry`:

```
ch @ addProperty[chemistry]
```

and now we can use it:

```
ch@get[chemistry,"C"]

(* 0.032 *)
```

If you then need to add another property (for example, and index of a given element), you can do it:

```
index = Range[Length[elements]];
ch@addProperty[index]
```

and now you can use it too:

```
ch@get[index,"C"]

(* 1 *)
```

One remaining flaw is that the properties are associated with specific values of specific variables (`chemistry` and `index` here). This can be easily changed by using some e.g. string names and changing the signature of `addProperty` accordingly.

#### Permanent installation of `OO.m`.

To permanently install `` OO` `` on your machine, you can use

```
Import["https://raw.github.com/lshifr/ProjectInstaller/master/BootstrapInstall.m"]
```

which will install the [ProjectInstaller](https://github.com/lshifr/ProjectInstaller) project into your `$USerBaseDirectory/Applications`, and then call

```
Needs["ProjectInstaller`"] 
ProjectInstall[URL["https://gist.github.com/4266126/download"]]
```

alternatively, you can use the `copyRemote` utility by Rolf Mertig. Note however that ProjectInstaller installs entire project, which includes not just `OO.m`, but also example notebook and a file with project meta-data, so I recommend using that.

Comment: Thanks Leonid, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ahhhh Glad I could help, and thanks for the accept. See also my edit with an object-oriented approach.

Answer (score 17):

Use a dispatch table. It is an optimized element -> value lookup table that can be used to replace an element any time with its value. Now it does matching-and-finding every time, but if your list is not too big, this is pretty fast.

```
dispatch = Dispatch[Thread[elements -> chemistry]];

ratio[elemA_, elemB_, disp_] := (elemA/elemB) /. disp;
ratio[elemA_, elemB_] := ratio[elemA, elemB, {}];

ratio["Ti", "N", dispatch]
```

> ```
> 0.114943
> ```

```
ratio["Ti", "N"]
```

> ```
> "Ti"/"N"
> ```

Comment: Thanks István, your answer was very educational as well, but I chose Leonid's because his was a drop-in replacement for my elem function.

Comment: @ahhh No problem, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 9):

With the new [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) data structure introduced in the Wolfram Language/Mathematica 10 (you can try it now on the Raspberry Pi), this becomes extremely very simple to write and lookups are highly efficient as well.

```
property = AssociationThread[elements -> chemistry]
property["Ni"]
(* 0.06 *)
```

Comment: Interesting but I'm wondering whether there are any advantages over simply `chem=Thread@[elements-> chemistry]; Ni/.chem`  ?

Comment: @DavidCarraher With `Dispatch`, it comes very close to `Association`'s timings. However, I like the cleanliness of using `Association`, especially with how the code reads. See also [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41757/5) and Leonid's comments under it for the advantages of `Association`.

Comment: Very useful link. Thanks.

Comment: And maybe change `Association@Thread` to `AssociationThread`

Answer (score 4):

You can use indexed variables with a shortcut function to define a long list of indices and values, like so:

```
indexedVariable[var_, indicesValues__] := With[{dict = List[indicesValues]}, Scan[(var[#[[1]]] = #[[2]]) &, dict]];
indexedVariable[chemistry, {"C", 0.032`}, {"Mn", 1.2`}, {"S", 0.0259`}];
chemistry["C"];
```

This will let the engine handle optimization of your lookups as it would any other indexed variable.

This method gleaned from http://www.physic.ut.ee/~kkannike/english/prog/mathematica/ under "TRUE DICTIONARIES IN MATHEMATICA 5", which includes many other helper functions for getting lists of keys and values and pairs which could be used to replicate your functionality of printing formulas numerically or symbolically.