# Why is there no PositionFunction in Mathematica?

Tags: functions, function-construction, syntax, language-design

Too often I have seen the programs of inexperienced users greatly slowed by using `Position` in an iterative fashion, when far faster would have been to compute a look-up table for positions beforehand.

*Mathematica* provides such functionality for `Nearest` and `Interpolation` "out of the box" with the syntax of `function[data]` along with dedicated functions `NearestFunction` and `InterpolatingFunction`.

There is no equivalent with `Position[data]` producing a `PositionFunction` object.  I observe that `Position` appears to be used more often than either of the other functions so this seems like a regrettable omission.  Two complications I can think of are:

- the levelspec of `Position`
- the handling of patterns

Based on this I ask:

1. What other complications are there for creating a PositionFunction?
2. How best can such a function be implemented?
3. How can the utility and performance of the function be maximized?
4. All limitations considered would such a function be valuable?
   Why is there no such functionality in *Mathematica*?

Comment: I belong to the team of `Position[]`-users... :-(

Comment: @RodLm I'm not sure how to read that; often `Position` is *well* used too, and I certainly use it a lot myself (not implying that makes it right).  Rather, certain uses of it are quite slow.  I hope to bring attention to the issue and perhaps develop a useable general function.

Comment: BTW, congrats for the 60K ! Is there any way to "suggest" this function in the next version of *Mathematica*?

Comment: @RodLm -- Thanks!  You're getting ahead of the issue as I hope this questions helps establish whether such a function is even practical.

Comment: I can speak for myself, as I have several notebooks where I use `Position`. So, I believe `Position` is used more often than you think by the vast majority of users (not only unexperienced ones)...

Comment: @RodLm Yes, I think `Position` is commonly used by many people, and many of its applications are good.  I don't mean to imply that `Position` itself is slow, only a certain use where it is used repetitively.  I want to make sure that is clear.

Comment: I find it funny that I really only started to use `Position` after participating here. I think this site has warped my sensibilities. :D

Comment: In [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22599/accessing-list-elements-by-name/22601#22601), I described some implementation techniques which may also be applicable here.

Comment: @Leonid if you can spare the time I'd love to see you tackle this problem in earnest.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, +1, I think `PositionFunction` were (only) beneficial in the case were one has *repeated* position queries about the *same* input expr. The equivalent is certainly the case for `NearestFunction` and `InterpolationFunction`. What is a (strong) usage case for a `PositionFunction` that meets this criterion?

Comment: @ruebenko That is not the case I'm thinking of.  The usual misuse is something like:  `a = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {5000}];
Table[{i, Position[a, i]}, {i, 1, 1000}] // Timing // First` when magnitudes faster would be `Sort[{#[[1, 1]], #[[All, 2]]} & /@ 
   GatherBy[Transpose[{a, Range@Length@a}], First]] // Timing // First`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I think we are talking about the same thing: How about this: `(* retruns a PositionFunction[data] which is listable *)
pf = Position[a,levelSpec,n,opts];
pf[Range[10] (*pattern*)]
{
 {{2}, {3}, {7}, {19}, {33}, {35}, {37}, {41}, {50}},
 {{1}, {39}, {42}},
 {},
 ...
 }`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, or if it's not listable `pf /@ Range[10]`

Comment: There does occur to me a 'reason' for why there is no `PositionFunction`, and that is that `Nearest` and `Interpolation` are "subject matter" functions whereas `Position` is more a language thing. E.g. hypothetically, `Nearest` could be constructed from a variety of data structures because all that matters is the *mathematical* distance between one unit and another, whereas `Position` is entirely about the specific list structure you are using. Not saying I'd agree with this, but there is this conceptual difference which may have something to do with the absence of a `PositionFunction`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have updated my answer and I feel it is now quite complete. I did look a Szabolcs `GatherBy` inversion trick, but I think we cannot efficiently use it in the general case. The only thing that is missing now is to use your idea when level 1 and `Heads-> False` is specified, but I'd say that is a minor point.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I see no mention of the new-in-10 `PositionIndex` in the other answers, which takes a list (or association) of values and returns a 'reverse lookup' that maps from values in the list to the positions where they occur:

```
In[1]:= index = PositionIndex[{a, b, c, a, c, a}]

Out[1]= <|a -> {1, 4, 6}, b -> {2}, c -> {3, 5}|>
```

It doesn't take a level spec yet (though I do want to add that).

In any case, the returned association is already a function in some sense because of the function application way of doing key lookup in associations.

So in the above example you could write `index[a]` to get a list of places where `a` occurred.

Comment: This would be helpful (so +1), even without *levelspec*, except that [*it is horribly slow.*](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54853/121)  Hopefully that problem can quickly be fixed for the next point release.

Comment: By the way, as an insider would you please consider answering this?: [(44189)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44189) I am unable to.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it is only horribly slow when there are a large fraction of repeated values. For small lists or large lists with unique values it is plenty fast. But yes, it will be fixed.

Comment: I have Accepted this answer, at least for now.  There are certain aspects of the question that I hope to see natively addressed some day, e.g. *levelspec*.

Answer (score 14):

This is perhaps a place to start:

```
position[expr_, level_: 1] :=
 With[{positionData =
    SortBy[
      #[[1, 1]] -> #[[All, 2]] & /@
       GatherBy[Extract[expr, #, Verbatim] -> # & /@ Position[expr, _, level], First],
      Min[Length /@ #[[2]]] &
    ] // Dispatch},
  Replace[#, positionData] &
 ]
```

The second argument controls the depth of the indexing.  An example:

```
f = position[x^2 + y^2 + q_^r_, 3];

f[2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}
> ```

Due to the use of `Verbatim` patterns are matched literally, which deviates from normal `Position` behavior:

```
f[_]
```

> ```
> {{3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 2}}
> ```

Comment: Hm.. Are you aware that setting x=y breaks the positionFunction? i.e. f[y] -> {1,1} . Verbatim does not have HoldAll. Maybe use HoldPattern (as well as Verbatim?). I guess it would be even better if you could shield the symbols from updates. Compare, with your definitions, `{Drop[Trace[f, TraceOriginal -> True], 2], Update[y]; 
 Drop[Trace[f, TraceOriginal -> True], 2]}`

Comment: @Jacob Good point; I should add that, or change to DownValues on a HoldAll function, etc.  I only intended this to be a rough start.

Comment: Maybe I should have added that I respect that it is rough start. It seems like a good start though :)

Comment: Are you a tribal Wizard now :D? Or witch doctor, perhaps (I call dibs on that name!)

Comment: @rm-rf See if you can figure out what that's a picture of, assuming you have not already seen it.  It's quite amazing. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I hadn't seen it and didn't figure it out either. But I did find out what it was and they're amazing and pretty!

Comment: @rm-rf Don't miss the [videos.](https://www.youtube.com/user/Peacockspiderman)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Alas, I don't have the time for this at the moment. May be later. But I also think that this makes real sense only for regular structures such as flat lists, may be multi-dimensional arrays too. For symbolic expressions, I think it will be more trouble than it's worth in the majority of cases. And when not, one should make a custom optimization (this case is not likely to be run into by a novice user anyway).

Answer (score 7):

In the function I propose, I build an association with keys that are not supposed to be evaluated. There are some issues with this, see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60538/4330) by Taliesin, with the following quote.

> generally this just sounds like a dangerous and confusing game to play, to me.

I think the function presented in this answer deals with the complications you mention reasonably well. It uses an option to set the levelspec. To see how patterns are handled, see the section Verbatim.

Concerning point (1),(2) and (3): Before there were a lot of additional complications. But I now that we have `Association` we no longer have to deal with those. Making this work with held expressions is just a matter of being thorough in surrounding expressions with `Hold` and `Unevaluated.` My intuition is also that `Association` should have better performance than a `Dispatch` table or something similar. An `Association` should be unbeatable in terms of how long it takes to look up a particular sub-expression. But maybe we should do a proper comparison.

```
ClearAll[positionIndexGeneral]
Options[positionIndexGeneral] = {Heads -> True};
SetAttributes[positionIndexGeneral, HoldAll];
positionIndexGeneral[expr_, lev_: {1,Infinity}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{subExprs, positions, len, together, gathered, hGathered, 
   gatheredSubExprs, gatheredPos},
  subExprs = 
   Level[Unevaluated@expr, lev, Hold, Heads -> OptionValue[Heads]];
  positions = 
   Position[Unevaluated@expr, _, lev, Heads -> OptionValue[Heads]];
  len = subExprs // Length;
  together = Transpose[{List @@ Hold /@ subExprs, positions}];
  gathered = GatherBy[together, First];
  hGathered = Hold@Evaluate@gathered;
  gatheredSubExprs = hGathered[[All, All, 1, 1, 1]];
  gatheredPos = gathered[[All, All, 2]];
  AssociationThread @@ {Unevaluated @@ gatheredSubExprs, gatheredPos}]
```

Example:

```
a = 3;
positionAssoc = 
 positionIndexGeneral[{a, 2, {3, 4, a}}]
positionAssoc[Unevaluated[a]]
```

> ```
> {{1},{3,3}}
> ```

corresponding to

```
Position[Unevaluated@{a, 2, {3, 4, a}}, Unevaluated[a]]
```

> ```
> {{1},{3,3}}
> ```

**Verbatim**

Note that in general we are simulating how `Position` works with `Verbatim`.

```
positionAssoc = positionIndexGeneral[{a, 2, {3, 4, a_}}]
positionAssoc[a_]
```

> ```
> {{3,3}}
> ```

Corresponding to

```
Position[Unevaluated@{a, 2, {3, 4, a_}}, Verbatim[a_]]
```

> ```
> {{3,3}}
> ```

To simulate how `Position` works without `Verbatim` in this way is probably not very useful. There are infinitely many patterns against which an expression can be tested, so of course we cannot make a big lookup table. For a very specific pattern like `List | Hold` we might make some specialised code that looks up both `List` and `Hold` in the association.

**Timing**

My function can kind of compete with a specialised function by Mr.Wiz in the 1D case, and of course it dwarfs the built in `PositionIndex` for large data.

```
f[x_] := AssociationThread @@ {Hold[
       Unevaluated[x]][[1, {1}, #[[All, 1]]]], #} &@
  GatherBy[Range@Length@x, Hold[x][[{1}, #]] &]
```

Now let's make some data and compare

```
data = RandomInteger[999, 1*^5];
(jacobGen = 
    positionIndexGeneral[Evaluate@data, {1, 1}, Heads -> False]) // 
  Timing // First
(mma1D = PositionIndex[data]) // Timing // First
(wiz1D = f[data]) // Timing // First
Position[data, 115] === jacobGen[115] === List /@ wiz1D[115] === 
 List /@ mma1D[115]
```

> ```
> 0.214873
> 0.174309
> 0.164100
> True
> ```

```
data = RandomInteger[10, 1*^5];
(jacobGen = 
    positionIndexGeneral[Evaluate@data, {1, 1}, Heads -> False]) // 
  Timing // First
(mma1D = PositionIndex[data]) // Timing // First
(wiz1D = f[data]) // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.235508
> 4.119624
> 0.153041
> ```

```
data = RandomInteger[10, 1*^6];
(jacobGen = positionIndexGeneral[data, {1, 1}, Heads -> False]) // 
  Timing // First
(wiz1D = f[data]) // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 2.294256
> 1.703060
> ```

**Possible improvement**

When we only want the expressions at level 1, the function provided by Mr.Wizard is faster. With some good metaprogramming it should be possible to get the best of both worlds.

**Appendix**

It would of course have been cooler to write something like

```
ClearAll[positionIndexGeneral]
Options[positionIndexGeneral] = {Heads -> True};
positionIndexGeneral[expr_, lev_: {1,Infinity}, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 AssociationThread @@
      {
       Unevaluated @@ #2[[All, All, 1, 1, 1]]
       ,
       Function[{x}, x[[#]] & /@ #[[All, All, 2]]]@
        Position[expr, _, lev, Heads -> OptionValue[Heads]]
       } &[#, Hold@Evaluate@#] &@
  GatherBy[Transpose[{List @@ Hold /@ #, Range[# // Length]}] &@
    Level[expr, lev, Hold, Heads -> OptionValue[Heads]], First]
```

but I prefer the style with `Module`(/`Block` when possible) for debugging, as well as to immediately see what happens first.

Answer (score 6):

This is a similar approach to Mr. Wizard's I suppose, but using the function's `DownValues` instead of a dispatch table to store the rules.

One major difference is that this code won't work with data containing pattern objects (I guess this might be fixable with `Verbatim`).

The expression is traversed using `MapIndexed`, for each part visited the position is `Sow`ed, with the part's value as the tag. The actual downvalues are set afterwards using the third argument of `Reap` (the first time I've ever used it I think).

```
makePositionFunction[f_Symbol, data_, level_: {-1}] := Block[{},
  ClearAll[f];
  Reap[
   MapIndexed[Sow[#2, #1] &, data, level, Heads -> True],
   _, (f[#] = #2) &];
  f[other_] := Position[data, other, level]]
```

Example:

```
data = RandomInteger[1000, {3000, 20}];

makePositionFunction[pos, data];

First @ Timing[test1 = Table[pos[i], {i, 1000}]]
(* 0. *)

First @ Timing[test2 = Table[Position[data, i], {i, 1000}]]
(* 3.532 *)

test1 == test2
(* True *)
```

The "PositionFunction" defaults to using plain old `Position` for any search patterns which have not been precomputed:

```
pos[n_ /; n < 20] // Length
(* 1225 *)
```

Comment: +1 for the post.  However, I considered `MapIndexed` and went with `Position` and `Extract` for one reason: held expressions (or subexpressions).  To make this robust I think you'll need something additional, e.g. `MapIndexed` onto an explicitly held expression and then a `Cases` to pull out those parts.  You'll also have to consider how to keep parts extracted from a held expression from evaluating.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good point, I didn't consider held expressions. I suppose one *could*, with sufficient code gymnastics, work with held expressions in `MapIndexed` - but then why bother when you've already shown how to do it neatly with `Position` and `Extract`. Great question, by the way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I find it very frustrating that there is no function like ScanIndexed. That would work perfectly with held expressions. I have spent a lot of time trying to find an alternative for held expressions to the construct with (Inner, my addition) Position and Extract (that I suppose will soon appear in my answer), to try do something with Scan and/or MapIndexed. Maybe we can discuss things soon?

Answer (score 4):

I think the complexities of things like `PatternTest` will obstruct any kind of data structure for searching for general pattern matches.  I think some regularity, either with the pattern as in Mr Wizard's answer or with the expression as in Leonid Shifrin's remark, will be needed in order to beat using `Position`.  Jacob Akkerboom has pointed out problems with what to do if variables in expression change after the position function is computed.

That said, here's a start along the lines of Mr. Wizard's answer, using literal matches (literally, as you will see ;-).  When he mentioned `NearestFunction` in the question, I thought, I wonder if there is a way to measure the "pattern-distance" between expressions.  I don't think it's likely in general, but you can in the case of exact matches.  Recall that `Nearest` uses `EditDistance` when the data are strings.

```
ClearAll[position2, positionFunction]; 
positionFunction[nf_NearestFunction, expr_][x_] := 
 With[{arg = ToString[FullForm @ x]},
  With[{pos = nf[arg]}, 
   If[pos =!= {} && ToString[FullForm @ Extract[expr, Prepend[First @ pos, 1]]] === arg, 
    pos, {}]]];
Format[positionFunction[nf_NearestFunction, expr_]] := positionFunction["<>", Short[expr]];
position2[expr_, level_: 1] := positionFunction[
  Nearest[ToString[FullForm @ Extract[expr, #]] -> # & /@ Position[expr, _, level]],
  HoldForm[expr]]
```

Mr.Wizard's example:

```
pf = position2[x^2 + y^2 + q_^r_, 3]
```

> ```
> positionFunction["<>", x^2 + y^2 + q_^r_]
> ```

```
pf[2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}
> ```

```
pf[_]
```

> ```
> {{3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 2}}
> ```

Another example:

```
gf = position2[Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], Infinity]
```

[image]

```
gf[Polygon]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0},
>  {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 0}}
> ```

Comment: I love how your positionFunction looks. Also, you code is so short compared to mine ;).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom  Thanks.  I think to do this right, the code might have to be long, though.