# What is the fastest way to get a list of subexpressions and their positions?

Tags: core-language

I have spent quite some time trying to figure out what the fastest way is to get a list lists of all subexpressions and their positions. I have tried things with MapIndexed, which seems ideal in cases where we have an expression in which no functions with Hold-Attributes are present that we can let evaluate freely. For Held expressions, however, I found using MapIndexed complicated and I was unable to get a practical solution using this. Furthermore, I have tried things with Extract and Position.

All these things were hinted at in the comments of/answers to [the positionFunction question by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/4330), which caused me to be interested in this. Because I have spent time on this and because I feel this is quite a fundamental question, I would like to get some feedback. To be fair, I am also quite glad with my own answer, as it is considerably faster than the alternatives I found (although it took me a long time), but if there are better alternatives I would be even gladder to know. Lastly, it may be nice for me to refer to this Q&A later, if I ever write a good answer to Mr.Wizards question.

**The question is**:
What is the fastest way to get a list of lists of subexpressions and their positions, that works with held expressions?

**Test expressions**

Let's make a big expression to do tests with. Let

```
body[i_][n_] := If[n < i, head[body[i][n + 1], body[i][n + 1]], 1];
tree12 = head[body[12][1]];
tree3 = head[body[3][1]];
```

We have

```
LeafCount[tree12] == 2^12 && LeafCount[tree3] == 2^3
```

> (True)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand your goals, though I too wish there were a cleaner way to do this.
I presume that you are dissatisfied with the performance of this fairly direct solution:

```
index[expr_] := {Extract[expr, #, HoldComplete], #} & /@ Position[expr, _]
```

Your own method using both `Position` and `Level` is a clever way to vectorize this as it were.  I do not understand why you gave your `toExprPosLists` function a hold attribute at this would seem to only complicate using it.  Perhaps you would find value in this:

```
index2[expr_, lev_ : {0, -1}] := 
 Thread[{Level[expr, lev, HoldComplete, Heads -> True], 
   HoldComplete @@ Position[expr, _, lev]}, HoldComplete]
```

This returns something similar to your function and it is faster:

```
time = Function[x, First@Timing@Do[x, {500}]/500, HoldAll];

toExprPosLists @@ {tree12} // time
index[tree12]              // time
index2[tree12]             // time
```

> ```
> 0.003432
>
> 0.005648
>
> 0.00184
> ```

Comment: Ah yes, it is faster indeed :). And even applying Rule on level {1,1} afterwards is faster than the alternative with `Inner[Rule, exprs, pos, HoldComplete]`. I do not see why though. You are right about the argument HoldAllComplete. If the user has not given his expression head HoldComplete, then it will be really hard to stop the expression from rebuilding anyway (though it is possible, using OwnValues). One subtlety is that it may be nicer to end up with something like HoldComplete[{...}] rather than HoldComplete[...]. Anyway, it is not so important. +1, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Jacob Glad I could help, even if I was bumbling. :-)  If you want the inner list try: `List @@@ HoldComplete @@ {HoldComplete[1 + 1, 2 + 2]}` (faster) or `HoldComplete[1 + 1, 2 + 2] /. h_[a__] :> h[{a}]`.  I suppose `index2` is faster because it is just less convoluted.

Comment: You provoked an edit with that comment ;). Note that I am not offended by the word convoluted. However, I think I do have some valid points and I hope they are not discarded because your code is so much better (and my code is so long). I'm pretty sure I have showed that Inner is just inferior to Thread if Thread can be used. That is unexpected to me, but it is exactly the kind of thing I'd like to be aware of :).

Answer (score 4):

**Solutions with Inner**

Here is the function I came up with

```
ClearAll[toExprPosLists];
SetAttributes[toExprPosLists, HoldAllComplete]
toExprPosLists[expr_] :=
 Inner @@
  Function[
    Hold@
     Evaluate[
      List,
      Unevaluated @@
       Level[Unevaluated@expr, {0, Infinity}, #, Heads -> True],
      Position[Unevaluated@expr, _],
      #
      ]
    ]@Function[Null, HoldComplete[List@##], HoldAllComplete]
```

We then have

```
head = 6;
{
   # (*timing*),
   {
    (HoldComplete @@@ #2)[[1, All]] // Length,
    Position[tree12HC, _] // Length,
    2^12 + 2^11 + 2
    } (*number of subexpressions*)
    ,
   #2[[All, ;; 5]] (*sample of subexpressions*)
   } & @@
 (toExprPosLists @@ List@tree12HC // Timing)
Clear[head]
```

> {
>   0.015144, (*timing*) 
>   {6146, 6146, 6146}, (*number of subexpressions*) 
>   
>    HoldComplete[{{HoldComplete, {0}}, {head, {1, 0}}, {head, {1, 1, 
>        0}}, {head, {1, 1, 1, 0}}, {head, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}}}] (*sample of subexpressions*)
>   }

**Remarks**

All the `HoldComplete` wrappers and the `HoldAllComplete` attributes serve to minimize overhead. To see what I mean, consider the difference between

```
head = List;
Trace[Hold @@ tree12HC, TraceOriginal -> True] // LeafCount
Clear[head]
```

> 16411

```
head = List;
Trace[tree12HC, TraceOriginal -> True] // LeafCount
Clear[head]
```

> 4101

I am not sure if I have succeeded in stopping all "rebuilding of expressions". But at least I have kept such considerations in mind while making the function :).

**"Less convoluted"**

Note that we could also have written

```
ClearAll[toExprPosLists3];
toExprPosLists3[expr_] :=
 Inner[
      List,
      Level[Unevaluated@expr, {0, Infinity}, HoldComplete, Heads -> True],
      HoldComplete@@Position[Unevaluated@expr, _],
      HoldComplete
    ]
```

But this appears to be slower. Also this does not look much more convoluted than Mr.Wizards answer, it only uses `Inner` instead of `Thread`. However, it is slower than the function I defined above. I think I understand a little bit why this function is slower, that is why I came up with the "convoluted version" in the first place :). Below is an explanation.

**About the optimization**

All of this has to do with the fact that it takes a bit of time to do something like `HoldComplete@@expressionWithManyArguments`. That is also the reason why I let the function return something of the form `HoldComplete[List[___]]` rather than `HoldComplete[___]`, because it is more likely that you will need a list than something with head HoldComplete. This allows you to prevent one more `List@@expressionWithManyArguments`. Also in case you do `var = expressionWithManyArguments` and then do `List@@var`, you are using twice as much memory as necessary.

However, all of that optimization/"convolution" is minor compared to the difference in performance between Inner and Thread, it seems.

**Showing that Inner is bad**

To take this argument that Inner is worse than Thread to the extreme, let's make our own version of Inner (that will only work correctly with a very specific subset of possible arguments). We could set

```
myInner[head1_, exprs__, head2_] :=
 head1 @@@ Thread[{exprs}, head2]
```

and

```
ClearAll[toExprPosLists4];
SetAttributes[toExprPosLists4, HoldAllComplete]
toExprPosLists4[expr_] :=
  myInner[
        List,
        Level[Unevaluated@expr, {0, Infinity}, HoldComplete, 
   Heads -> True],
        HoldComplete @@ Position[Unevaluated@expr, _],
        HoldComplete
      ]
```

Which turns out to be faster, because as it turns out Inner is just not suitable for the job.

**Comparison of timings**

```
toExprPosLists @@ tree12HC // Timing // First
toExprPosLists3[tree12] // Timing // First
toExprPosLists4 @@ tree12HC // Timing // First
index2[tree12, {0, Infinity}] // Timing // First
```

> 0.015313 
>   0.016765 
>   0.010508 
>   0.006448

**Remarks about Mr.Wizards answer**

So, `Thread` seems to be the best option for this (I think it is not possible to use `MapThread`, though maybe we can use InheritedBlock). I think there is no optimization to be done w.r.t avoiding apply, because of the stringent syntax of `Thread`. In my opinion, it is a bit of a shame we end up with something matching `HoldComplete[___]` rather than `HoldComplete[{___}]`, but I do not see a good way around this.

Comment: Interesting observations, as usual.  +1

Comment: Here's an observation of my own: you appear to be confusing `HoldAllComplete` with `HoldComplete`; the former is an *attribute*, not a container.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah, yes, I confuse those two all the time when I type :P. I will see where I went wrong. I am glad you like the observations.

Comment: Yikes, I really messed it up I see. Funny/crazy that it still works. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard maybe I should try to see if some of the answers here can be improved using `myInner2[head1_, exprHead1_[args1___], exprHead2_[args2___], head2_] :=
  Apply[Unevaluated[head2], 
  Unevaluated[head1] @@@ 
   Thread[{HoldComplete[args1], HoldComplete[args2]}, HoldComplete]]`. I would almost say that version of Inner is always superior for Held expressions.. Of course using `Thread` directly must be better. Btw I hope I am not disturbing you too much lately :).

Comment: You're not disturbing me, but I'm not being much help either.  It's nice weather now and I'm not spending a lot of time on this site.  Come winter I'll likely be much more active.  By the way, I think a lot of your questions go over the heads of many readers (including me sometimes) but I think they are very valuable.  I hope you continue to explore the inner workings of *Mathematica*, and I'm sure I'll learn a lot from you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am glad to hear that :). The weather has been great here as well. Please do enjoy :).