# Change sublist based on position

Tags: list-manipulation

Supposed that:

```
list = {2, 3, 5, 7, 9};
sublist = {{3, 3, 5}, {2, 2, 2, 7, 9}};
```

I want to change each sublist in sublist as following:

1. Find the positions of elements in sublist in list.So,

> ```
> {3, 3, 5} -> {2, 2, 3} and {2, 2, 2, 7, 9} -> {1, 1, 1, 4, 5}.
> ```

```
sublist1 = {{2 ,2, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 4, 5}};
```

2,Change each sublist in sublist1 to sparsearray:

> ```
> {2, 2, 3} -> {0, 2, 1, 0, 0} and {1, 1, 1, 4, 5} -> {3, 0, 0, 1, 1}.
> ```

```
sublist2 = {{0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 1}};
```

How to do it?

Comment: What should be the length of each last sublist? The same as `list`'s?

Comment: Yes.Each sublist's length is the same as list.

Answer (score 4):

It's perhaps simpler to use rule replacements and the efficient `Tally` to get the same answer than `Position` (which is inefficient):

```
list /. Join[Rule @@@ Tally@#, {_Integer -> 0}] & /@ sublist
(* {{0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 1}} *)
```

Comment: I must say I like it :P but also I think that this will not be the fastest solution for every variation of initial list/sublist. I suppose more answers will appear and someone will make some comparisons :p

Comment: @Kuba It probably won't be the fastest, but it should be reasonably efficient, since it's not walking through `list` multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

**new** - all in one.

```
Map[Function[x, Count[x, #] & /@ list], sublist]
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
> ```

---

**old** - step by step.

1)

```
sublist1 = Map[Position[list, #][[1, 1]] &, sublist, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 4, 5}}
> ```

2)

```
sublist2 = SparseArray[Rule @@@ Tally[#], Length@list] & /@ sublist1
```

> ```
> {SparseArray[<2>, {5}], SparseArray[<3>, {5}]}
> ```

```
Normal /@ sublist2
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
> ```

Comment: `f[list_List, subList_List] := 
  Map[Position[list, #] &, sublist, {Infinity}];`?

Comment: @belisarius out= `{{3, 3, 5}, {2, 2, 2, 7, 9}}` something is not ok.

Comment: Might be more efficient if you do the tally first, since position is generally an inefficient operation: `Composition[Normal, SparseArray[#, Length@list]&, 
  Position[list, #][[1, 1]] -> #2 & @@@ # &, Tally] /@ sublist`

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks for the remark. I've got even shorter code now :)

Comment: @rm-rf Yes yes, I know, short but not effective with very sparse arrays.

Comment: @Kuba See my answer :)

Comment: Thank Kuba. I test the two methods with a huge size of sublist. It seems like that the old one is more efficient than the new.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one-liner. Maybe not the fastest, but the most compact yet. I think it also makes it easier to understand what's being done.

```
Outer[Count,sublist,list,1]

{{0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 1}}}
```

Comment: My apologies but I must condemn this method.  I am well known for my fixation on terse code but I cannot excuse this; it is exactly the kind of application that I lamented in [Why is there no PositionFunction in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/121).  (I mean no offense to you by this; it's nice clean code but I consider it a "siren song" that new users *must* be warned against.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't say it was efficient, but I do think it's the clearest statement yet of *what* is to be done. Perhaps its best use would be in a comment, along with something like "that's what we need, and here's how we get it efficiently."

Comment: I agree that it is the clearest code.  I think it deserves more than a comment.  (You'll notice that I did not down-vote this answer.)  I suppose I was overly harsh yesterday, but at the same time I think there is a genuine need for a warning with such things.  I think what I'll do, if I have time, is provide timings for the methods posted; then people can see for themselves how these behave without me unfairly singling out your method for criticism.

Answer (score 2):

I presume your starting list will never contain duplicates. Therefore:

1.

```
sublist1 = sublist /. MapIndexed[#1 -> First[#2] &, list]
(* {{2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 4, 5}} *)
```

2.

```
sublist2 = BinCounts[#, {1, 6, 1}] & /@ sublist1
(* {{0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 1}} *)
```

Comment: `BinCounts` is/was quite slow in v7; how does it compare to `Tally` in v9?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard been offline for a few days. In my experience `BinCounts` is usually slow -- I usually look for alternatives if speed is important -- but offered it here as an alternative. Whether it is viable depends on the real data to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Also assuming `list` is duplicate free I propose this:

```
sparse[main_][sub_] := Tally[main ~Join~ sub][[All, 2]] - 1
```

Now:

```
sparse[list] /@ sublist
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
> ```

This works by "priming" `Tally` with the elements of the main list to get the order desired, then subtracting one to correct the totals.  [SubValues notation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/121) is used.

---

I like the style of the code above but this is slightly faster:

```
sparse2[main_, sub_] := (Tally[main ~Join~ #][[All, 2]] & /@ sub) - 1

sparse2[list, sublist]
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach:

```
Function[u, 
  Reap[Sow[1, #] & /@ u, list, Total@#2 &][[2]] /. {{} -> 0, {x_} :> 
     x}] /@ sublist
```