# GroupBy several keys while keeping the Dataset as a Table (List of Associations)

Tags: dataset

Assume you import data from a Table source of the following format.

```
<< GeneralUtilities`; fields = {"Country", "Region", "BU", "Year", 
"Date", "Sales"};
organization = {{"Argentina", "LATAM", "Americas"}, {"SouthAfrica", 
    "Africa", "EAME"}, {"Brazil", "LATAM", "Americas"}, {"Japan", 
    "Japan", "APAC"}, {"Australia", "ASEAN", "APAC"}, {"Germany", 
    "Europe", "EAME"}};
SeedRandom[0];
list = Flatten[
   Table[Join[
     organization[[i]], {year, DateObject[{year, month, 1}], 
      RandomInteger[{100, 1000}]}], {i, 6}, {year, 2004, 
     2013}, {month, 1, 6, 5}], 2];
sales = Dataset[AssociationThread[fields, #] & /@ list]
```

[image]

I would like to summarize the data at the year level. If working with a database, an SQL command of the following format would allow you to create a dataset that is still flat.

> SELECT sales.Country, sales.Region, sales.BU, sales.Year,
>   Sum(sales.Sales) AS SumOfSales FROM sales GROUP BY sales.Country,
>   sales.Region, sales.BU, sales.Year;

[image]

Using

```
sales[GroupBy@Key["Country"], GroupBy@Key["Region"], 
 GroupBy@Key["BU"], GroupBy[Key["Year"]], Total, "Sales"]
```

Creates a multilevel hierarchical data structure, which is not as simple to operate as a table type of dataset.

[image]

Is there a way to operate (total,mean, median,etc) on a dataset by grouping on several keys of interest while keeping the dataset flat the same way as done with the SQL procedure?

Comment: PatoCriollo: the GeneralUtilities package does not seem to be documented in V. 10. Could you please describe what is it used for and how you found it?

Comment: @magma See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54853/why-is-the-new-positionindex-horribly-slow/54865#54865). I believe that package was first introduced in that answer by Taliesin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably far from ideal, but this works:

```
sales[
  GroupBy[{#Country, #Region, #BU, #Year} & -> Key["Sales"]]
][Normal, Total
][All, Apply[Append]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Thanks to WReach for the tip on the unusual but useful linebreak pattern.)

---

**Update**

This works too, and preserves the keys.  Now if only I could specify `Normal` to be descending here ...

```
sales[
 GroupBy[#, KeyTake[{"Country", "Region", "BU", "Year"}] -> KeyTake["Sales"], Total] &
][Normal
][All, Apply[Join]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Brilliant! Dataset[AssociationThread[Drop[fields, {5}], #] & /@sales[
  GroupBy[{#Country, #Region, #BU, #Year} & -> Key["Sales"]]
][Normal, Total
][All, Apply[Append]]//Normal] puts the keys back again.
]

Comment: @PatoCriollo That came out really wordy though, I'm hoping for a shorter solution!  It would be good to have something like Merge that doesn't merge each key using the same function.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm using your answer for a similar problem that I have, but I don't really understand the syntax.  I was hoping you could help. How are [Normal][All,Apply[Join]] applied to the result from Total?

Comment: @MitchellKaplan This dataset contains an association, the keys of which are also associations.  `Normal` will convert this outer association, which has the form `<| <|...|> -> <| "Sales" -> 1 |>, <|...|> -> <| "Sales" -> 2 |>, ... |>` to a simple list of rules, `{  <|...|> -> <| "Sales" -> 1 |>, <|...|> -> <| "Sales" -> 2 |>, ... }`.  You can see e.g. the first element of this list using `...[Normal][1]`.  Now what we want to do is join the left-hand-side of `->` together with its right-hand-side into a single association.  Instead of having `<| "a" -> 1 |> -> <| "b" -> 2 |>` we want ...

Comment: ... `<| "a" -> 1, "b" -> 2 |>`.  This is what `Apply` is good for: change the head `Rule` (i.e. `->`) into something else.  What we need here is to change it to `Join`.  `Apply[Join][...]` is equivalent to `Apply[Join, ...]` so we can use the form `Apply[Join]`.  I hope this clears it up a bit.  Regarding this method, while it works, it's probably not efficient and I am not really happy with it.  I find it too convoluted.  I am hoping for something simpler ...  I'm not yet experienced with Dataset, and even though my answer got accepted, I'm not too confident about it.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think I'm getting it, thanks!  For my data, the efficiency is not a problem, about 1,000 rows.  Your explanation also helped clear up a few things in my mind about how operators work with a dataset.

Comment: @Szabolcs okay, I'm not getting it.  How does the "#" in the GroupBy work?

Comment: @Szabolcs To simulate Merge with key-dependent merging function, one could use `sales[GroupBy[
      KeyTake[{"Country", "Region", "BU", "Year"}] -> 
       KeyTake["Sales"]]][All, Transpose][All, {"Sales" -> Total}][
  Normal][All, Apply[Join]]`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an alternative:

```
 Query[Map[Total] /* Normal /* Map[Apply@Append]]@
 sales[GroupBy[{#Country, #Region, #BU, #Year} & -> Key["Sales"]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OR

```
sales[GroupBy[{#Country, #Region, #BU, #Year} & -> Key["Sales"]]][
 Map[Total] /* Normal /* Map[Apply@Append]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is another possibility:

```
sales[
  GroupBy[KeyTake[{"Country","Region","BU","Year"}]] /* Normal /* (Association@@@#&)
, <| "Sales" -> Query[Total, "Sales"] |>
]
```

This approach has the interesting property that it can be "scaled up" to perform multiple aggregations at the same time:

```
sales[
  GroupBy[KeyTake[{"Country","Region","BU"}]] /* Normal /* (Association@@@#&)
, <| "Sales" -> Query[Total, "Sales"]
   , "MinYear" -> Query[Min, "Year"]
   , "MaxYear" -> Query[Max, "Year"] |>
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: This is the best answer. It works great even though I am a bit puzzled about how it works :)

Answer (score 5):

A possibility

```
sales[
 GroupBy[KeyTake[{"Country", "Region", "BU", "Year"}] -> KeyDrop["Date"]] /* Values,     
 merge[{"Sales" -> Total}, First]
 ]
```

`merge` is an operator such that you can specify a merging function for    particular keys, and a default one

```
merge[r : {__Rule}, def_] := Merge[Identity] /* Query[{
     Query[KeyDrop@Keys@r, def],
     Query[KeyTake[#], #2] & @@@ r} // Flatten] /*
  Merge[First]
```

or something among these lines

```
groupBy2D[groupby_, newCols : {__Rule}] := 
 With[{tr = Transpose[#, AllowedHeads -> All] &},
  Query[
   GroupBy[KeyTake[groupby]] /* Values,
   Query[{First, tr /* Query[<|newCols|>]}] /* Merge[First] /* 
    KeyTake[groupby]]
  ]
```

so that

```
sales[
 groupBy2D[
  {"Country", "Region", "BU", "Year"}, 
  {"SumOfSales" -> (Total@#Sales &)}
  ]
 ]
```

These are probably not too efficient

Comment: groupBy2D[groupby_, newCols : {__Rule}] := 
 With[{tr = Transpose[#, AllowedHeads -> All] &},
  Query[GroupBy[KeyTake[groupby]] /* Values, 
   Query[{First, tr /* Query[<|newCols|>]}] /* Merge[First] /* 
    KeyTake[Join[groupby, Keys[newCols]]]]
  ], just changing last KeyTake from KeyTake[groupby] to  KeyTake[Join[groupby, Keys[newCols]]] includes the newCols in the returned Dataset. Very handy construction, thank you @Rojo

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit late to add a comment, but I found that GeneralUtilities` has a some operators such as AssociationPairs and AssociationMapThread. I used them to adjust the internal Dataset format. Since a GroupBy leaves a single association in the Dataset whose keys are the grouping keys, you need to process what is essentially a single association and make each k-> v in that association a "row." I used

```
dsGroupByResult[AssociationPairs]
```

to fix the structure. However it loses the column names and the "rows" are now lists.

To add columns back in, I use AssociationMapThread to "add" the columns back in and restructured back into a list of associations. My GroupBys usually output an association of values (e.g. mean, min, max for a numerical leaf column) so I just use ##2 since it already has keys on the values.

```
dsGroupByResult[AssocationMapThread[<|"theGroupingKeyColumnName"->#1 (*or whatever *), ##2|>]&]
```

I think both of these functions should be included in the standard package.