# Change dataset key name

Tags: dataset

Using the example in the documentation, how would I make a new dataset with the key "b" changed to key "h".

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

I tried:

```
dataset /. "b"-> "h"
```

and also

```
Normal[dataset] /. "b"-> "h"
```

Which don't work.  This comes up when I get sums using `GroupBy`.  I'm using code from Szabolcs which results in my getting the sums, but they have the same name as the original key.  I still don't really understand the code I'm using so I don't know how to handle it there, if possible.  Eventually I have to use a `JoinAcross` to merge these totals with the original detail, and I need separate key names.

Szabolcs code is:

```
sales[
GroupBy[#, KeyTake[{"Country", "Region", "BU", "Year"}] -> KeyTake["Sales"], Total] &
][Normal
][All, Apply[Join]]
```

[Source of Szabolcs code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57016)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We can explicitly construct a new association with key names of our choosing:

```
dataset[All, <| "a" -> "a", "h" -> "b", "c" -> "c" |>]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Alternatively, a function could be applied to the keys:

```
dataset[All, KeyMap[# /. "b" -> "h" &, #] &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Note that a bug in the V10.0.0 type system prevents us from using the operator form `KeyMap[# /. "b" -> "h"&]`.  *(2020 Update: in more recent versions we can also write `KeyMap[Replace["b" -> "h"]])`.*

Or, we could explicitly add the key `"h"` and drop the key `"b"`, although this will re-order the keys in the resultant association:

```
dataset[All, <| #, "h" -> #b |> & /* KeyDrop["b"]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Or, we could split each association into its keys and values, operate upon the keys, and then thread the results back together into an assocation:

```
dataset[All, AssociationThread[(Keys@# /. "b" -> "h") -> Values@#] &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: I gave up on `KeyMap` because `dataset[All,KeyMap[#/."b"->"h"&]]` wouldn't work. Is this expected?

Comment: @Pickett I believe it should work, and I reported a bug to WRI.  Consider that `Dataset[<| a -> 1 |>][KeyMap[f]]` works, but `Dataset[<| "a" -> 1 |>][KeyMap[f]]` doesn't.  Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: OK, thanks. You have my +1 of course.

Comment: `KeyMap[Replace["b" -> "h"]]` is a little more concise.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks, I have added a _2020 update_.  I am a little daunted at the thought of going back and reviewing all the older Dataset posts on the site for obsolete constructions.  The ones dating back to 10.x are particularly suspect since back then the type system had to be hacked more often than not.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dataset[Association /@ (Normal@Normal@dataset /. "b" -> "h")]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This could also be expressed as `dataset[All, Normal /* (# /. "b" -> "h" &) /* Association]`.

Answer (score -2):

```
    dataset = {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>, <|"a" -> 6, 
   "b" -> 5, "c" -> 9, "d" -> 2|>};
    changeKeys[assoc_, suffix_] := KeyMap[# <> suffix &, assoc]
    changeKeys[#, "1"] & /@ dataset
```

It turns out the in the help file under datasets there is an answer but it currently doesn't work.  There must be a bug. The code above works. If some of your  datasets are one row (i.e. an association) be sure to put curly brackets around it.

Comment: The question was how to change specific key name, not add a suffix. Also, the `dataset` is not a `Dataset[...]`.