# Truncating a list once all members of a set have appeared?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider if you would the case where we have some list of elements:

```
list0 = {54, 4, 7, 9, 3, 54, 4, 20, 2, 456, 2, 3};
```

And we have some target list:

```
targetList = {2, 3, 4, 7};
```

We'd like to scan from left to right through `list0` and chop off an RHS tail at the moment all elements in `targetList` have appeared.  With the example given we would have:

```
list0chopped = {54, 4, 7, 9, 3, 54, 4, 20, 2};
```

As an output.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose:

```
truncate[a_List, b_List] :=
 a ~Take~ Max @ Lookup[PositionIndex[a][[All, 1]], b, 0]
```

For maximum performance replace `PositionIndex` with `cleanPosIdx` from [Why is the new PositionIndex horribly slow?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54853/why-is-the-new-positionindex-horribly-slow/55967#55967)

I'll add comparative timings later if I get the chance.

Comment: Very nice. I like Lookup[....,0] to get rid of MissingKey.+1

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this would help:

```
list0[[;; Max[First /@ (Position[list0, #] & /@ targetList)]]]

(*{54, 4, 7, 9, 3, 54, 4, 20, 2}*)
```

In case `targetList` contains elements not in `list0` then:      `(*Thanks to Chris Degnen*)`

```
 list0[[;; Max[First /@ (Position[list0, #] & /@ Intersection[list0, targetList])]]]
```

Comment: +1, also with `If[Intersection[list0, targetList] == Sort@targetList, ...]`

Comment: I have an aversion to mapping `Position` across a list; see: [(25591)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/121).  You can avoid that by using `PositionIndex` as I did in my answer.  However since since my answer is otherwise very similar +1.

Answer (score 2):

This s/b snappy for lists of any type:

```
f=#1[[;; With[{l = Length@#2}, 
     Max[Sort[Partition[Ordering[Join[#2, #1]], 2, 1]][[;; l, 2]]] - l]]] &;

f[list0, targetList]
```

> {54, 4, 7, 9, 3, 54, 4, 20, 2}

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = Module[{i = Length @ #2}, While[Not[ContainsAll[#[[;; i++]], #2]]]; #[[;; i - 1]]]&;

f1[list0, targetList]
```

> {54, 4, 7, 9, 3, 54, 4, 20, 2}

```
f2 = Replace[#, {x__,y___} /; ContainsAll[{x}, #2] :> {x}]&
f2[list0, targetList]
```

> {54, 4, 7, 9, 3, 54, 4, 20, 2}

Answer (score 1):

If the list consists of positive integers smaller than some reasonable maximum, then the following function should be pretty fast:

```
trunc[a_, b_] := Module[{c = ConstantArray[0, Max[a]]},
    c[[Reverse @ a]] = Reverse @ Range @ Length @ a;
    Replace[
        MinMax[c[[b]]],
        {
            {0, _} -> a,
            {_, i_} :> a[[;;i]]
        }
    ]
]
```

Here is `trunc` applied to the OP example:

```
trunc[
    {54, 4, 7, 9, 3, 54, 4, 20, 2, 456, 2, 3},
    {2, 3, 4, 7}
]
```

> {54, 4, 7, 9, 3, 54, 4, 20, 2}

And, here `trunc` is compared to some of the other answers:

```
a = RandomInteger[{1, 10^4}, 10^5];
b = RandomSample[Range[10^4], 100];

r1 = trunc[a, b]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = truncate[a, b]; //AbsoluteTiming
r3 = algohi[a, b]; //AbsoluteTiming
r4 = klgr1[a, b]; //AbsoluteTiming
r5 = klgr2[a, b]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 == r2 == r3 == r4 == r5
```

> {0.002184, Null}
>
> {0.030749, Null}
>
> {0.742536, Null}
>
> {31.082, Null}
>
> {53.734, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 0):

```
list0 = {54, 4, 7, 9, 3, 54, 4, 20, 2, 456, 2, 3};
targetList = {2, 3, 4, 7};

Module[{list0chopped = {}, l2 = list0, tg = targetList},
           While[l2 =!= {} && tg =!= {},
                 AppendTo[list0chopped, First[l2]];
                 tg = Delete[tg, FirstPosition[tg, l2[[1]], {}, {1}]];
                 l2 = Rest[l2]
          ];
         list0chopped]
```

> {54, 4, 7, 9, 3, 54, 4, 20, 2}

If the same element appears several times in `targetList`, it should appears the same number of times in `list0` before `list0chopped` is returned