# Can Mathematica delete some of the 0's from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list: `{1,2,3,0,0,4,5,0,0,0}`.  I want to delete the `0`'s occurring after the last positive integer.  In other words, I want Mathematica to return: `{1,2,3,0,0,4,5}`.

Comment: {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0} /. {a___, b_ /; b > 0, 0 ..} -> {a, b}

Comment: Somewhat related: [(69613)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69613/121)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use

```
{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0} /. {a___, 0 ...} :> {a}
```

`/.` is synonymous with `ReplaceAll`. It tries to replace values on the left hand side with the rules on the right hand side. In this case `{a___, 0...}` is the pattern; `a___` matches zero or more elements, and `0...` matches zero or more zeroes. `:> {a}` takes the `a` that corresponds to the matched expression and returns it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the code.  I was completely unaware of ... Repeated.

Comment: Note that this only works because by default the first pattern is treated as `Shortest`.  In reverse order this fails: `{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5} /. {0 ..., a___} :> {a}`.  Adding a `Shortest` or `Longest` corrects the problem:  `{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5} /. {Longest[0 ...], a___} :> {a}`

Answer (score 7):

```
Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros@{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0}
(* {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5} *)
```

Timing comparison with @ciao's `dropper` and `dropper2`:

```
test = Join[RandomChoice[{1, 10} -> {1, 0}, 100000], ConstantArray[0, 100000]];

First@AbsoluteTiming[res0 = Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros@test;]
(* 0.005003 *)
First@AbsoluteTiming[res1 = dropper@test;]
(* 0.016011 *)
First@AbsoluteTiming[res2 = dropper2@test;]
(* 0.002004 *)
Equal @@ {res0, res1, res2}
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 6):

The `TakeWhile` and replacement based answers will be *very* slow with large lists and/or large lists with many trailing zeroes.

Something like

```
dropper=With[{s = Split[#]}, If[s[[-1, 1]] == 0, Join @@ (Most@s), #]] &;
```

will be ~2000X faster on a list of 50K length vs a replacement solution, advantage growing with size. There are other even faster methods for really huge flat numeric lists... e.g.:

```
dropper2 = 
 With[{s = SparseArray[#, Automatic, 0]["NonzeroPositions"]}, 
       If[s === {}, {}, #[[;; s[[-1, 1]]]]]] &;
```

Using:

```
test = Join[RandomChoice[{1, 10} -> {1, 0}, 100000], ConstantArray[0, 100000]];
```

The `SparseArray` is ~10X faster than `dropper`, which is itself ~15X faster than the `TakeWhile`, which is itself ~365X faster than the replace-based solution, making the `SparseArray` ~45,000X faster for this test...

Comment: `SparseArray[#, Automatic, 0]` is somewhat verbose; `Automatic` and `0` are the defaults so you need only `SparseArray[#]`.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, @Bill's and @Pickett's clean answers do not quite delete the 0s after "the last *positive integer*."  A teeny alteration fixes Bill's answer:

```
{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4.2, 0, 0, 0} /. {a___, b_Integer /; b > 0, 0 ..} -> {a, b}
```

Comment: What if there are negative values interspersed to the right of the last positive integer? (My answer made some assumptions about the data that I think are reasonable, so I did not address this myself.)

Comment: I read the original question to mean:  "take the last positive integer in a list, and if all the remaining elements of the list are all $0$, delete them."  Thus `{0, -4, 0, 0}` would be unchanged.  I *think* that's what the poser meant.

Comment: For what its worth,  my list only contains positive integers.  My question  probably should have been stated: I want to delete all the 0's after the last non-zero entry.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh!  Then that is a very simple problem and several solutions exist, such as the ones provided by @Bill and Pickett.  (Try to be extremely clear and precise in your question posing from now on.)

Answer (score 5):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0};

f = Drop[#, -Length[TakeWhile[Reverse[#], Function[b, b == 0]]]] &;

f[a]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}

Comment: +1,  `LengthWhile` can be used here as well.

Answer (score 4):

Too late for the party so fun solution:

```
ToString @ Row @ list ~ StringTrim ~ ("0" ..) // ToExpression // IntegerDigits
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}
> ```

I feel like it is a duplicate but I can't find it...

Comment: This kills leading zero as well, which it should not, and it doesn't work with integers larger than 9.  This solves both problems and it's shorter:  `StringTrim[ToString[list], ", 0" ... ~~ "}"] <> "}" // ToExpression` :^)

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`):

```
{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0} //. {a___, 0} :> {a}
```

> {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0};
```

Using `SequencePosition` (new in 10.1)

```
list[[;; SequencePosition[list, {a_?Positive, 0}][[-1, 1]]]]
```

{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
Flatten @ ReplaceAt[{0 ...} :> Nothing, -1] @ Split[list]
```

{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}

Answer (score 2):

**Using `IntegerExponent`:**

From the documentation:
`IntegerExponent[n,b] gives the number of trailing zeros in the digits of n in base b.`

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0};
Drop[list, -IntegerExponent[FromDigits[list]]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}

Comment: Very nice and a well deserved (+1). Very interesting approach

Answer (score 2):

Using `FirstPosition`

```
list = {1,2,3,0,0,4,5,0,0,0};
Drop[list,-First@FirstPosition[Reverse[list],_Integer?(#>0&)]+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ReplaceList`:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0};

ReplaceList[#, {a__, b_ /; b > 0, 0 ..} :> Splice@{a, b}] &@list

(*{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {a__, b_ /; b > 0, 0 ..} :> Splice@{a, b}]

(*{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}*)
```

Or using `SequenceSplit`:

```
First@SequenceSplit[list, s : {a__, b_} /; b > 0 :> s]

(*{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}*)
```

Or using `FirstCase` and `Span`:

```
#[[Span[1, #[[1]]] & @@ Position[#, FirstCase[Reverse@#, a_ /; a > 0]]]] &@list

(*{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}*)
```