# (Sparse Array) Can Mathematica delete some of the 0's from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

This question continues form [Can Mathematica delete some of the 0's from a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/can-mathematica-delete-some-of-the-0s-from-a-list)

This time I want to delete zeros before the first positive integer.

I have a list: `{0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,4,5}`.

I want *Mathematica* to return: `{1,2,3,0,0,4,5}`.

From [ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao)'s answer

```
dropper2 = With[{s = SparseArray[#, Automatic, 0]["NonzeroPositions"]}, If[s === {}, {}, #[[;; s[[-1, 1]]]]]] &;

Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros@{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0}

res0 = Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros@test;
```

returns the wanted results (which was deleting zeros after the integers).

But how can I modify this code into deleting first zeros?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `Reverse` before & after will do it.  Might be better ways, though.

Comment: `#[[First@FirstPosition[#, a_?Positive] ;;]] &@{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}`. Would this work in general? I think so, unless your list can have negative numbers.

Comment: `Drop[list, FirstPosition[list, _?(# != 0 &)][[1]] - 1]`

Comment: Reverse[Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros@Reverse[list]] but now I see Michael E2 already suggested it...

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5};
```

Using [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html):

```
list //. {0, a___} :> {a}
```

> {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}

Answer (score 4):

Two ways:

From my comment:

```
Reverse@Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros@
  Reverse@{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}
(*  {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}  *)
```

Using `` System` `` level functions:

```
Drop[#, LengthWhile[#, MatchQ[0]]] &[{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}]
(*  {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}  *)
```

Comment: It can be simplified a bit by using the operator form of MatchQ: Drop[#, LengthWhile[#, MatchQ[0]]] &

Comment: @GustavoDelfino Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}

NestWhile[Rest, list, First@# == 0 &]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}

Or

```
While[First@list == 0, list = Rest@list]; list
```

> {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}

If the entries of `list` are all single-digit integers you can also use

```
IntegerDigits@FromDigits@{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}
```

> {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}