# Slicing an Association with named key span without normalizing?

Tags: associations, index, query

Is there way to slice an Association with named key span?

Span currently doesn't accept named keys:

```
<|"z" -> 1, "x" -> 2, "b" -> 3, "a" -> 4|>  // Query["x" ;; "a"]
```

> Missing["PartInvalid", "x" ;; "a"]

And neither does passing Key["x"] and Key["a"] to Span.

Here is a workaround using Position - which only matches Values in an Association - so relies on 1. normalizing, 2. projecting the first component of the matching Positions then 3. querying the rebuilt association using the resulting position Span.

```
keySpan[k1_, k2_][as_Association] := 
  Query[{Identity, Normal /* Position[k1 | k2] /* Map[First] }  /* 
     Replace[{a_, pos_} :> Query[Span[pos]][a]]][as];
```

Then:

```
<|"z" -> 1, "x" -> 2, "b" -> 3, "a" -> 4, "c" -> 5|>  // keySpan["x", "a"]
```

> <|"x" -> 2, "b" -> 3, "a" -> 4|>

Is there a method that avoids normalizing the association?

Comment: What objects are "stored" in the association values? Strings and/or numbers or more general expressions?

Comment: @AntonAntonov - as far as I know arbitrary expressions can be Values, including eg graphics. Whereas Keys are intended to be verbatim, so not patterns unless perhaps Held or Inactivated- haven't tested that. But Keys can also be compound, eg List, Association, Graphics etc.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if this is useful to you but it seems a little cleaner than your own code:

```
asc = <|"z" -> 11, "x" -> 22, "b" -> 33, "a" -> 44|>;

keySpan[k_Span][asc_Association] :=
 asc[[k /. First /@ PositionIndex@Keys@asc]]

asc // keySpan["x" ;; "a"]

asc // keySpan["z" ;; "a" ;; 2]

asc // keySpan["b" ;;]
```

> ```
> <|"x" -> 22, "b" -> 33, "a" -> 44|>
>
> <|"z" -> 11, "b" -> 33|>
>
> <|"b" -> 33, "a" -> 44|>
> ```

Note:

- If you are going to use this function a lot on the same association it would be beneficial to memoize the `PositionIndex` output.

---

With memoization as noted above:

```
mem : keySpanMem[asc_Association] := mem = First /@ PositionIndex @ Keys @ asc

keySpan[k_Span][asc_Association] := asc[[ k /. keySpanMem @ asc ]]
```

This will be counterproductive if the Association changes very frequently.

For the purpose of benchmarking (with or without memoization) please use `cleanPosIdx` from:

- [Why is the new PositionIndex horribly slow?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54853/why-is-the-new-positionindex-horribly-slow/55967#55967)

Comment: Agreed, thanks, nice.

Comment: @alancalvitti You're welcome.  Okay, see my update for a bit more flexibility.

Comment: Yes, even nicer with the ;; syntax and the ability to skip. Would like to do a timing study before accepting, will likely edit the Q including a random test Association. Perhaps you can show the best method for memoization - I usually use a  x := y = f  pattern.

Comment: @alancalvitti Example added.

Answer (score 6):

From version 10.4 onward, we can define `keySpan` like this:

```
keySpan[k1_, k2_] :=
  Replace[<|___, s:PatternSequence[k1 -> _, ___, k2 -> _], ___|> :> <|s|>]
```

so that:

```
$a = <| "z" -> 1, "x" -> 2, "b" -> 3, "a" -> 4 |>;

$a // keySpan["x", "a"]

(* <|"x" -> 2, "b" -> 3, "a" -> 4|> *)
```

We can make this more robust by handling some corner cases:

```
keySpan[k1_, k2_] :=
  Replace @
    { <|___, s:(k1 -> _), ___|> /; k1 === k2 :> <|s|>
    , <|___, s:PatternSequence[k1 -> _, ___, k2 -> _], ___|> :> <|s|>
    , _Association :> (Message[keySpan::failed, k1, k2]; $Failed)
    , _ :> (Message[keySpan::object]; $Failed)
    }

keySpan::failed = "Cannot find key span '``' to '``'.";
keySpan::object = "Association
```

so then:

```
$a // keySpan["x", "b"]

(* <| "x" -> 2, "b" -> 3 |> *)


$a // keySpan["x", "x"]

(* <| "x" -> 2 |> *)


$a // keySpan["b", "x"]

(* keySpan::failed: Cannot find key span 'b' to 'x'.
   $Failed *)


$a // keySpan["x", "XYZ"]

(* keySpan::failed: Cannot find key span 'x' to 'XYZ'.
   $Failed *)


$a // keySpan["XYZ", "XYZ"]

(* keySpan::failed: Cannot find key span 'XYZ' to 'XYZ'.
   $Failed *)


{1, 2, 3} // keySpan["x", "a"]

(* keySpan::object: Association expected.
   $Failed *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also an interesting approach. I'd like to do a timing study to compare your answer w/ Mr.Wizard's and numeric Span.