# Multi-dimensional PositionIndex

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I've noticed that [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) does not take a level spec like most related functions. So while it's very useful on 1D lists, I can't really use it to get a index of a matrix for example. Now I'm wondering what an efficient replacement is.

I'm aware of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54853/2305) which contains two handwritten alternatives to `PositionIndex` that are faster in the 1D case.

However, since I know that the values in my matrix are small consecutive integers (in fact it's a label matrix obtained from [`MorphologicalComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MorphologicalComponents.html)), I don't really need the result to be an association, and I've found a simple `Array` over `Position`s to be faster:

```
matrix = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {1000, 1000}];
Array[Position[matrix, #] &, Max@matrix]; // AbsoluteTiming
GroupBy[Tuples[Range@Length@matrix, 2], matrix[[## & @@ #]] &]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.910396, Null}
> {2.73593, Null}
> ```

The `Array` approach seems wasteful though because it needs to go over the matrix several times. Then again, I can speed this one up a bit more in my own case, because I don't care about the positions of the `0`s in the label matrix.

Is there a better way to generalise the `GroupBy` approach to multiple dimensions? Or is there some third approach that would be a useful replacement for `PositionIndex` when I'm dealing with data that has more structure than a 1D list?

Comment: `Merge[PositionIndex /@ matrix, Join]`

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev Wouldn't that only give me the second index of each index pair? I guess I could do that both on `matrix` and its transpose and then zip the two results together. I might try that, but I'm not sure it will be particularly efficient (although then I can swap in the faster replacement for `PositionIndex` again).

Comment: `Merge[Table[Thread[{i,#}]&/@PositionIndex[matrix[[i]]],{i,Length@matrix}],Join]`

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev It needs to be `Join@@#&`, but that's already faster, thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, using `cleanPosIdx` or `myPosIdx` from the other question is slower than `PositionIndex` in this case.

Comment: I was glad to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function based on the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) [`GroupByList`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GroupByList):

```
pIndex2[m_] := ResourceFunction["GroupByList"][
    Tuples @ Range @ Dimensions @ m,
    Flatten @ m
]
```

Comparison:

```
r1 = posInd[matrix]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = pIndex2[matrix]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === Values @ KeySort @ r2
```

> {0.046, Null}
>
> {0.0394, Null}
>
> True

The `GroupByList` scales better with the number of keys:

```
matrix = RandomInteger[{1, 10^3}, {1000, 1000}];
r1 = posInd[matrix]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = pIndex2[matrix]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === Values @ KeySort @ r2
```

> {0.68, Null}
>
> {0.050, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 3):

This is the fastest I can think of right now:

```
posInd[matrix_] := Block[{inds, flatmat},
  inds = Flatten[Outer[List, #, #] &@Range[Length@matrix], 1];
  flatmat = Flatten[matrix, 1];
  Pick[inds, flatmat, #] & /@ Range[Max@matrix]
  ]
```

On my MacBook Pro from 2013 with Mathematica 10.0.2.0:

```
matrix = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {1000, 1000}];
m1 = Array[Position[matrix, #] &, Max@matrix]; // AbsoluteTiming
m2 = GroupBy[Tuples[Range@Length@matrix, 2], matrix[[## & @@ #]] &]; // AbsoluteTiming
m3 = Merge[Table[
    Thread[{i, #}] & /@ PositionIndex[matrix[[i]]], {i, 
     Length@matrix}], Join @@ # &]; // AbsoluteTiming
m4 = posInd[matrix]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.866475, Null}`
>
> `{2.824167, Null}`
>
> `{0.297523, Null}`
>
> `{0.088725, Null}`

```
m1 === m4
```

> `True`

Comment: Nice. This can be sped up a little more by constructing the indices with `Tuples[Range@Length@matrix, 2]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Merge[Table[Thread[{i,#}]&/@PositionIndex[matrix[[i]]],{i,Length@matrix}],Join@@#&]
```