# Replacing members of a list with elements sampled without replacement from another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of element pairs:

```
pairList = {{1,2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};
```

I'd list to pick a subset of the elements in this list:

```
pairListSubset = {2, 5};
```

Now, wherever any `pairListSubset` element occurs, I'd like to replace it with an element sampled without replacement from list in `replacementSets` occurring at the same index position in `pairListSubset`.  Extending the previous example:

```
replacementSets = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}};
```

With the example provided the result of this procedure may result in one of the following nine possibilities:

```
pairListFinal = ... 

{{1,"a"}, {"b", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "d"}}
{{1,"a"}, {"c", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "d"}}
{{1,"b"}, {"c", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "d"}}
{{1,"a"}, {"b", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "e"}}
{{1,"a"}, {"c", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "e"}}
{{1,"b"}, {"c", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "e"}}
{{1,"a"}, {"b", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "f"}}
{{1,"a"}, {"c", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "f"}}
{{1,"b"}, {"c", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "f"}}
```

How can I concisely carry out this list operation?  To simplify things, it would be fine to pick the first element of each `replacementSets` list, then the second element, and so on.  Its not important to sample randomly without replacement.

Comment: I answered using *Mathematica* 10 functionality (`GroupBy`).  If you are using an earlier version please let me know and I shall provide an alternative.

Comment: Just for anyone seeing this, I've commented on this posting below Mr. Wizard's answer.  Unfortunately I have only Version 8, but I'm coming around to buying v10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting data:

```
pairList = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};
pairListSubset = {2, 5};
replacementSets = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}};
```

`PositionIndex`-style function with *levelspec* (avoids mapping `Position`; [reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/121)):

```
posIdxLevel[x_, levelspec_, opts : OptionsPattern[Position]] :=
  GroupBy[Extract[x, #] &] @ 
    Position[pairList, _, levelspec, opts, Heads -> False]
```

Positions:

```
pos = posIdxLevel[pairList, {2}] /@ pairListSubset;
```

Substitutions:

```
subs = Join @@ 
   MapThread[Thread[#2 -> RandomSample[#, Length@#2]] &, {replacementSets, pos}];
```

Result:

```
ReplacePart[pairList, subs]
```

> ```
> {{1, "b"}, {"c", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "e"}}
> ```

Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange :-)

---

#### Version 5+ implementation of `posIdxLevel`

```
posIdxLevel2[x_, lev_, opts : OptionsPattern[Position]] :=
  Reap[
    Sow[#, Extract[x, #]] & ~Scan~
      Position[pairList, _, lev, opts, Heads -> False],
    _,
    Rule
  ][[2]] // Dispatch
```

Use with `ReplaceAll` rather than `Map` in this step:

```
pos = pairListSubset /. posIdxLevel2[pairList, {2}]
```

Comment: I noticed your comment on GroupBy while writing to ask about it!  Is there a workaround for an older version of Mathematica?  Version 8 or earlier?

Comment: Also, just as a comment, I find your alias to be fairly appropriate. :)

Comment: @user23512 backward-compatible version added.

Comment: Is it maybe the backward compatible version?  I noticed that pairList lists and pairListSubset must have the same dimension?  Also thank you so much for the backward compatible version!

Comment: @user23512 No, that's the result of my using `MapThread[. . . , {replacementSets, pos}]`.  I thought these two were always the same length.  How should it be handled if they are not?

Comment: I erred there; stupid mistake.  I think everything is fine.  pairListSubset and replacementSets need to be of the same length, but neither needs to be of length 2.

Comment: @user23512 Okay; the code should work correctly in that case.  If you have any problems let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This should be comparable on tiny lists and 20-50+X faster than the current posted solution on large lists, depending on number of replacements needed (at least when I compared to pre-V10 solution - I no longer have 10 installed, so did not bmark that 10-specific solution, perhaps Mr.W could bmark the two):

```
pairReplace[list_, pairsub_, subs_] :=
 Module[{f = Flatten@list, r, p, sr, c},
  r = Range@Length@f;
  p = Pick[ConstantArray[r, Length@pairsub], Subtract[f, #] & /@ pairsub, 0];
  sr = Flatten[MapThread[RandomSample[#, Length@#2] &, {subs, p}]];
  f[[Flatten[p]]] = sr;
  Partition[f, 2]];

pairList = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};
pairListSubset = {2, 5};
replacementSets = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}};

pairReplace[pairList, pairListSubset, replacementSets]

(* {{1, "b"}, {"c", 3}, {3, 4}, {4, "d"}} *)
```

For some use cases, the following simpler code can outperform the above:

```
pairReplace2[list_, sub_, reps_] := 
 Module[{f = Flatten@list, pp, gb, l = Length@sub},
  pp = Flatten@Join[sub, f];
  gb = Subtract[(GatherBy[Range@Length@pp, pp[[#]] &])[[;; l, 2 ;;]], l];
  MapThread[(f[[#1]] = RandomSample[#2, Length@#1]) &, {gb, reps}];
  Partition[f, 2]]
```