# Deleting all keys that have null values

Tags: associations

I have a notebook that I am working on that starts with an imported CSV file.  Many of the rows have blank data in them.  I have used the following command to establish a list of associations:

```
test = AssociationThread[First[rawdata] -> #] & /@ Rest[rawdata]
```

The `InputForm` of the above code produces an end result that is something like this:

```
test = {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> ""|>, <|"A" -> 3, "B" -> 4, 
   "C" -> 5|>, <|"A" -> "", "B" -> 6, "C" -> 7|>}
```

I want to remove the associations that have blank values so my end result would be more like this:

```
test2 = {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> 3, "B" -> 4, "C" -> 5|>, <|
   "B" -> 6, "C" -> 7|>}
```

Is there a simple way to drop all keys across all the entries that have null values?  I have looked into `KeyDrop` / `KeyDropFrom` but can't figure out a way to drop a key based on its value.

Based on [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74200/how-to-search-dataset-to-find-all-keys-share-same-value), I am thinking there may be a way to use `Position` or `PositionIndex`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
DeleteCases[test, "", {2}]
```

> {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> 3, "B" -> 4, "C" -> 5|>, <|"B" -> 6,
>      "C" -> 7|>}

Since this is about a list of associations, the level on which to search the pattern `""` is level 2 (only), therefore the `{2}` as third argument.

Comment: Ahh... that makes sense.  My earlier attempts didn't take into consideration the level of the key and value.

Answer (score 7):

[`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html):

```
Select[# != "" &] /@ test
```

> {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> 3, "B" -> 4, "C" -> 5|>, <|"B" -> 6,
>        "C" -> 7|>}

[`DeleteMissing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteMissing.html):

```
DeleteMissing[test /. "" -> Missing[], 2]
```

> {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> 3, "B" -> 4, "C" -> 5|>, <|
>     "B" -> 6,   "C" -> 7|>}

[`AssociationMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationMap.html):

```
AssociationMap[If[#[[2]] == "", Nothing, #] &] /@ test
```

> {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2|>, <|"A" -> 3, "B" -> 4, "C" -> 5|>, <|
>     "B" -> 6, "C" -> 7|>}

Comment: For some of my more complicated datasets, this actually provides me with even more functionality.  Thanks for the suggestion.