# Using Select on Dataset with missing keys

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, dataset

I have a very large dataset with about a million entries with up to 75 keys each.  Across the whole dataset about half of the keys are blank.  In order to reduce filesize, I have used the [following code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181559/deleting-all-keys-that-have-null-values) to remove all the blanks keys:

```
DeleteCases[Normal[data], "", {2}]
```

I have another much smaller expression with all the keys pointing to blank strings that I can use with `KeyUnion` to rebuild the original version if I need to.  This works great because it reduces the WL or MX file I am using by about half.

My issue comes when I am trying to use `Select`.  The ragged dataset works when all entries have the keys present, but if it missing the key, I get an error.

Consider this simplified example:

```
data = Dataset[{<|"Name" -> "Bob", "Location" -> "USA", 
    "Job" -> "Police"|>, <|"Name" -> "Jill", 
    "Location" -> "Canada"|>, <|"Name" -> "Joe", "Location" -> "USA", 
    "Job" -> "Teacher"|>}]
```

When all keys are there, I can use `Select` as normal:

```
Select[data, #Location == "USA" &]
```

But, if one of the entries is missing the key, I get an error:

```
Select[data, #Job == "Police" &]
```

[image: Error Message]

There are a few hacky things I can do.  I can use KeyUnion to rebuild a full database.

```
keys = <|"Name" -> "", "Location" -> "", "Job" -> ""|>
Select[KeyUnion[data, keys], #Job == "Police" &]
```

I can also use `KeyExistsQ` to do an initial select and then run from there:

```
Select[Select[data, KeyExistsQ["Job"]], #Job == "Police" &]
```

While both of these options yield the results I am looking for, neither are particularly effecient when working with a very large dataset.

I found [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119588/query-or-mapat-ragged-associations-or-ignoring-missing-values) from three years ago that addresses a similar issue with `Query`, but since that would have been on V10 and I am in V12, I was hoping something had changed to allow `Select` to work with missing keys.

Comment: Would `Select[data, Lookup[#, "Job", ""] === "Police" &]` be useful?

Comment: @WReach, That seems to do the same thing as the double select using `KeyExistsQ`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, but it ought to be faster as it only requires a single pass.  It is basically the same as the original `Select[data, #Job == "Police"&]` except that it is tolerant of missing keys.

Comment: @WReach, I will give it a shot.  My concern is that I have quite a few other functions I regularly use with `Select` such as `ContainsAny`, `MemberQ`, `StringContains`, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `Slot` function rather than #slot. This is nearly as fast as the #slot implementation, but doesn't cause this issue.

```
Select[dsa, #["Job"] == "Police" &]
```

You can also pattern match with `KeyValuePattern` instead of using `Select`, which returns the same result - from my testing, **this is the fastest option without this issue**:

```
Cases[dsa, KeyValuePattern[{"baz" -> "consequent"}]]
```

If you are married to using `Select`, you can use it with `KeyValuePattern` and `MatchQ`, but this appears slower:

```
Select[dsa, 
   MatchQ@KeyValuePattern[{"baz" -> "consequent"}]];
```

Another, slower option is to use `Part` instead of #slots. This is a lot slower.

```
Select[data, #[["Job"]] == "Police" &]
Select[data, Part[#, "Job"] == "Teacher" &]
```

Now to test:

```
words = RandomWord[20];

ds = Dataset@
      Table[AssociationThread[{"foo", "bar", "baz"}, 
        Table[RandomChoice@words, 3]], 100000]   
dsa = Dataset[<|"foo" -> #foo, 
         "bar" -> #bar, (If[RandomReal[] > .5, ("baz" -> #baz), 
           Nothing])|> & /@ Normal@ds]

(* --- *)

Select[dsa, #bar == "consequent" &] // RepeatedTiming // First

> 0.0816

Select[dsa, #[["baz"]] == "consequent" &]; // RepeatedTiming // First

> 1.14

Select[dsa, #["baz"] == "consequent" &]; // RepeatedTiming // First

> 0.114

Cases[dsa, KeyValuePattern[{"baz" -> "consequent"}]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

> 0.0943

Select[dsa, MatchQ@KeyValuePattern[{"baz" -> "consequent"}]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

> 0.123
```

So in order of fast-ness:

```
| Method                              | Speed on 100,000 test Dataset |
|-------------------------------------+-------------------------------|
| #key                                |                        0.0816 |
| Cases and KeyValuePattern           |                        0.0943 |
| #["key"]                            |                        0.1140 |
| Select, MatchQ, and KeyValuePattern |                        0.1230 |
| #[["key"]]                          |                        1.1400 |
|-------------------------------------+-------------------------------|
```

Comment: That certainly makes my code look much less hacked together.  But interestingly, it seems much slower on my full dataset.  In one example using `ContainsAny` using `Part` took about 6.8 seconds to run while using the double `Select` approach and `KeyExistsQ` only took 5.8 seconds.  In a `StringContainsQ` search the `Part` approach took 7.7 seconds while the double select only took 1.9 seconds.

Comment: Check my edit! 

Comment: Thanks for the edited solution @CarlLange.  I reran it with using the `Slot` function and it is much quicker than using `Part` but still slightly slower than double select.  With `ContainsAny` I was getting 5.8 for double select, 6.0 for `Slot` and 6.8 for `Part`. With `StringContainsQ` I got 1.9, 2.2, and 7.7 respectively.  The cleaner code is probably worth the very slight performance difference.

Comment: Yes, I think it's very slightly slower on really large datasets - I have noticed a difference of about 0.15 seconds between `#slot` and `#["slot"]` on a test dataset with a million rows, coming in at 1.14 seconds rather than 0.99 seconds. Even so, it's very much comparable and a lot faster than `Part` :)

Comment: Another edit - check out the `KeyValuePattern` stuff I added. It seems like the fastest option.