# Substitution and replacement in a matrix according to the position of an item in another matrix

Tags: matrix, replacement

I have the following problem and obviously I need help

1) a list of choices --- in fact journals but this doesn't matter

```
votes = {
   {ff, tt, ii, "-", "-", "-"},
   {ii, tt, gg, dd, hh, ff},
   {ii, tt, gg, "-", "-", "-"},
   {ff, tt, ii, gg, dd, hh},
   {hh, ii, gg, "-", "-", "-"},
   {hh, ff, ii, "-", "-", "-"},
   {ff, tt, ii, hh, dd, gg},
   {tt, ff, "-", "-", "-", "-"},
   {gg, ii, "-", "-", "-", "-"},
   {dd, ii, tt, "-", "-", "-"},
   {gg, dd, tt, "-", "-", "-"},
   {ff, hh, ii, gg, tt, dd},
   {ff, ii, gg, hh, "-", "-"},
   {ff, gg, hh, tt, "-", "-"},
   {tt, "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
   {ii, dd, gg, ff, "-", "-"},
   {ii, hh, gg, tt, dd, ff},
   {ii, hh, tt, gg, "-", "-"},
   {tt, dd, ii, hh, gg, ff},
   {ii, hh, gg, "-", "-", "-"},
   {ff, gg, ii, "-", "-", "-"},
   {hh, tt, ii, gg, ff, dd},
   {ii, tt, dd, "-", "-", "-"},
   {ii, tt, gg, "-", "-", "-"},
   {dd, tt, ii, gg, ff, hh},
   {tt, dd, ii, gg, hh, ff},
   {gg, dd, ii, tt, ff, hh},
   {ii, tt, gg, dd, "-", "-"},
   {ff, tt, ii, "-", "-", "-"},
   {hh, ff, tt, "-", "-", "-"},
   {tt, ii, hh, gg, "-", "-"},
   {ii, gg, ff, tt, dd, hh}
   };
```

I have constructed a table

```
tab = Table[{dd, ff, gg, hh, ii, tt}, {i, 1, 33}]
```

The two tables seem to have the same structure but votes is about the preferences and tab about the ranking of the journals.

I want to substitute in tab, for each line, the true position of each item in the corresponding line of votes. For instance as the line 2 of votes is ii, tt, gg, dd, hh, ff in tab the second line must be 4, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2.

I have tried some thing like that

ReplacePart[tab, {6, 2} -> Position[votes[[6, All]], ff][[1, 1]]]

which, according to what I think to have understood,  replaces the second element of the line 6 of tab by the position of ff in the line 6 of votes. But, I have not found how to iterate --- by functional programming --- or to loop by --- procedural programming --- on all elements of the table. For undocumented answers --- "-" ---, one can set a very large number.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Superb, it works but now how can I iterate ?

Comment: I think there is a error in your example. Do you really mean that the result shoul be 4,3,6,5,1,2 ?

Comment: Of course Andre, I have typeset too quickly its 463512

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done without explicitly creating `tab` for replacement.

```
tab = Function[{row},
  FirstPosition[row, #, #] & /@ {dd, ff, gg, hh, ii, tt} // Flatten] /@ votes
```

> {{dd,1,gg,hh,3,2},{4,6,3,5,1,2},{dd,ff,3,hh,1,2},{5,1,4,6,3,2},{dd,ff,3,1,2,tt},{dd,2,gg,1,3,tt},{5,1,6,4,3,2},{dd,2,gg,hh,ii,1},{dd,ff,1,hh,2,tt},{1,ff,gg,hh,2,3},{2,ff,1,hh,ii,3},{6,1,4,2,3,5},{dd,1,3,4,2,tt},{dd,1,2,3,ii,4},{dd,ff,gg,hh,ii,1},{2,4,3,hh,1,tt},{5,6,3,2,1,4},{dd,ff,4,2,1,3},{2,6,5,4,3,1},{dd,ff,3,2,1,tt},{dd,1,2,hh,3,tt},{6,5,4,1,3,2},{3,ff,gg,hh,1,2},{dd,ff,3,hh,1,2},{1,5,4,6,3,2},{2,6,4,5,3,1},{2,5,1,6,3,4},{4,ff,3,hh,1,2},{dd,1,gg,hh,3,2},{dd,2,gg,1,ii,3},{dd,ff,4,3,2,1},{5,3,2,6,1,4}}

In the above the default when the position is not found has been set the symbol being searched for.  In Mma [`Missing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html) is generally used for missing values and most (if not all) of the functions know to ignore `Missing` values. For example, you could use `Missing["NoVote"]` as the default.  Setting a default is optional.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

`ReplacePart` works with named pattern, for example you can do :

```
ReplacePart[tab, {i_, 2} :> Position[votes[[i, All]], ff][[1, 1]]]
```

So, once you will have corrected the question, the definitve answer is :

```
res = ReplacePart[tab,
{i_, j_} :> (If[# =!= {}, #[[1, 1]], tab[[i, j]] ] & @
   Position[votes[[i, All]], tab[[i, j]]])];

res // Grid
```

[image]

Do not forget to use a delayed rule (`:>` instead of `->` )

`ReplacePart` is not memory/speed optimal. It may be slow and memory consuming with large data sets.

I have followed your inital idea to use `ReplacePart`, but `ReplacePart` may not be the best approach.

Comment: Four nice answers that demonstrate the versatility of MA.

Answer (score 1):

```
alts = {dd, ff, gg, hh, ii, tt};

ranks = Replace[alts, x_ :> (Position[votes[[#]], x]/. {{} -> x, {{n_}} :> n}), 1]& /@
    Range[Length@votes];

Grid[Join[{alts}, ranks], Dividers -> All, Background -> {None, {Yellow}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Iterative use of [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) as used by others is rarely the most efficient approach.<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/121)</sup>

Here is a method that avoids `Position` (or [`FirstPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html)) entirely.

```
fW[votes_, key_] :=
  Module[{z, RL = Range@*Length},
    z = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions @ votes];
    DeleteCases[votes, "-", {2}] /.
      AssociationThread[key, RL @ key] //
      MapIndexed[(z[[#2, #]] = RL[#];) &];
    z
  ]
```

Existing answer code as functions for comparison:

```
fEdmund[votes_, key_] :=
 Function[{row}, FirstPosition[row, #, #] & /@ key // Flatten] /@ votes

fkglr[votes_, alts_] :=
  Replace[alts, x_ :> (Position[votes[[#]], x] /. {{} -> x, {{n_}} :> n}), 1] & /@ 
   Range[Length@votes];

fandre[votes_, key_] :=
 Module[{tab},
  tab = ConstantArray[key, Length@votes];
  ReplacePart[
   tab, {i_, j_} :> (If[# =!= {}, #[[1, 1]], tab[[i, j]]] &@
      Position[votes[[i, All]], tab[[i, j]]])]
  ]
```

Timings:

```
First @ RepeatedTiming @ #[votes, {dd, ff, gg, hh, ii, tt}] & /@
  {fEdmund, fkglr, fandre, fW}
```

> ```
> 0.000741
> 0.0014
> 0.00114
> 0.000147
> ```

So my code is five times faster than the next best method.

#### Note:

I chose to output zeros in the place of blank votes because this makes more sense to me.  If you prefer to have the vote items in the blanks you may replace the line

```
z = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions @ votes];
```

With:

```
z = ConstantArray[key, Length @ votes];
```