# intersection between two 2D arrays with labeled data is slow

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, function-construction

**Here is how to Generate data**

the function is below with two images to generate data

`img1`

[image]

`img2`
[image]

```
segmentImage[binarizedMask_?ImageQ] := 
Module[{seg, areas, indexMaxarea, maxArea},
seg = MorphologicalComponents@*ColorNegate@Dilation[binarizedMask, 1];
areas = ComponentMeasurements[seg, "Area"];
{indexMaxarea, maxArea} = First@MaximalBy[areas, Last] /. Rule -> List;
If[maxArea > 20000, ArrayComponents[seg, Length@areas, indexMaxarea -> 0], seg] ~
Dilation~1(* 20000 is just a threshold *)
];
```

generating data

```
{seg1, seg2} = segmentImage /@ {img1, img2};
```

**Now the question**

I have two 2-D arrays with dimensions `{651,823}`. Each array has labelled components i.e. at each position the value is either zero or an integer label. I have 51 objects in the first `seg1` and 50 objects in the second array `seg2`.

I wish to calculate the number of positions where a given object from the first array intersects the objects in the second array.

I have concocted this strategy but it seems terribly slow:

```
(pos = Table[
 Length@Intersection[Position[seg1, i], Position[seg2, j]], {i, 
  51}, {j, 50}];) // AbsoluteTiming
(* {143.607, Null} *)
```

Since these arrays need to be modified and consequently the intersections need to recalculated in an iteration later, I find that this is not the best way to do it.

Any ideas of speeding the process up will be welcomed.

the output i have looks something like this (each row represents an integer label in `seg1` and each column represents a label in `seg2` and the values represent the number of positions the labelled objects in both arrays intersect):

[image]

**Note:** In the image attached the values 267 and 564 in the first line delineates that the object (label 1) in `seg1` intersects an object labeled 5 and 7 in `seg2` at 267 and 564 positions respectively

Comment: In the image attached the value 267 in the first line delineates that the object (label 1) in `seg1` intersects an object labeled 5 in `seg2` at 267 positions

Comment: So are the two 2d arrays seg1 and seg2? In your pos printout, if each column reflects a single integer label and each row also reflects a unique integer label, how can you have two nonzero values in the first column, 204 and 118?

Comment: @MikeY sorry i read your comment late. The thing is the labeled data in `seg1` is `1,2,3....51` and `seg2` is labeled with `1,2,3....50` so the entries being non-zero means that the 4th and 6th labels in `seg1` intersect with the label 1 in `seg2`

Comment: maybe `SparseArray[SparseArray@Normal[Rest@Counts[Flatten[(1 - Unitize[seg1 - #]) seg2]]]&/@Range[51]]// Normal`?

Comment: @kglr let me add the raw images and the function from which the arrays are created. because currently your suggestion is giving a few errors.

Comment: @kglr please see the question with the input images and the only function needed to generate the two arrays

Comment: @Ali, could you try `Normal[SparseArray[SparseArray[#, {50}]&@DeleteCases[Normal[Counts[Flatten[(1 - Unitize[seg1 - #]) seg2]]],0->_]&/@Range[51]]]`?

Comment: So by intersect, you mean the corresponding positions in seg1 and seg2 are both nonzero, but they need not be the same?

Comment: @kglr can you post this as an answer. It works and is blazingly fast :)

Comment: @kglr 0.52 seconds !!

Comment: @MikeY the labels can be any number in both the arrays. If the same position in both arrays is occupied then that means an intersection. We are computing the number of positions where objects i = 1,2,...51 in `seg1` intersect with objects j = 1,2,3...50 in `seg2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like the following would be pretty fast:

```
intersections[r1_, r2_] := Module[{t},
  t = DeleteCases[Tally@Flatten[Unitize[r1 r2] (100 r1 + r2)], {0, _}];
  t[[All, 1]] = IntegerDigits[t[[All, 1]], 100];
  Normal[SparseArray[Rule @@@ t]]
]
```

This assumes that the labels are all less than 100. For the OP example:

```
res=intersections[seg1, seg2]; //AbsoluteTiming
res[[;;5, ;;5]]
```

> {0.006349, Null}
>
> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 267}, {0, 0, 6888, 0, 0}, {0, 6511, 0, 0, 0}, {204, 0, 0, 7249, 
>     70}, {0, 0, 0, 110, 3971}}

Comment: @AliHashmi It works fine for me. Perhaps you need to restart the kernel or clear some variables?

Comment: your method works like a charm !!  plus one'd it already  :)

Comment: @AliHashmi IMHO you really should change the Accept to this post.  I somehow overlooked it completely before starting on an answer myself, and it seems to be far and away the best method provided.

Comment: @CarlWoll there is a slight problem with your approach. Your method here gives a dimension of {50,50} whereas it should have been {51,50}

Comment: @AliHasmi The dimensions are `{50, 50}` because there is no intersection of the 51 from `seg1` with any of the integers from `seg2`. This could be fixed by adding a dimension specification to the SparseArray code. That is, using `SparseArray[Rule @@@ t, {Max[r1], Max[r2]}]` instead of `SparseArray[Rule @@@ t]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll thanks checked your comment late. Btw can your approach be modified to work with gaps in labels. lets say the first mask had labels such as {1,2,3 ... 35, 39,40,42}  (36, 37, 38 and 41 are not there). This is only an example. The gaps can exist anywhere. The second mask has regular labeling scheme with no gaps {1,2,3.. n} where n is the maximum value.

Comment: @CarlWoll i modified your function as: `overlapMatrix[segPrev_, segCurr_] := Module[{m,p1,p2,val,rules1,rules2},
{p1,p2} = Values@ComponentMeasurements[segPrev,"Label"]&/@{segPrev,segCurr};
val = Max[Max@p1,Max@p2]+1;
m = DeleteCases[Tally@Flatten[Unitize[segPrev segCurr] (val segPrev + segCurr)], {0, _}];
m[[All, 1]] = IntegerDigits[m[[All, 1]], val];
m =SortBy[m,First];
{rules1,rules2}=Thread[#-> Range@Length@#]&/@{p1,p2};
m = MapAt[ind\[Function]ind/.rules1,m,{All,1,1}];
m = MapAt[ind\[Function]ind/.rules2,m,{All,1,2}];
Normal@SparseArray[Rule@@@m,{Length@p1,Length@p2}] 
];`

Comment: @CarlWoll this passes in some cases (when i use different masks) and fails in other cases. I am not sure where i am going wrong to compute the overlaps.

Answer (score 9):

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 counts = Normal[SparseArray[SparseArray[#, {50}] &@ DeleteCases[
         Normal[Counts[Flatten[(1 - Unitize[seg1 - #]) seg2]]], 0 -> _] & /@ Range[51]]];]
```

> {0.30279, Null}

```
(pos = Table[Length@Intersection[Position[seg1, i], Position[seg2, j]], {i, 
        51}, {j, 50}];) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {122.747, Null}

```
counts == pos
```

> True

Comment: this is brilliant stuff !

Comment: Thank you @Ali. You might want to wait a while before accepting as questions with accepted answers are less likely to attract attention.

Comment: i wish i could go back and double like this one :)

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution using [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html)

```
a1 = Flatten[seg1] // PositionIndex;
a2 = Flatten[seg2] // PositionIndex;
a3 = Table[Length@Intersection[a1[i], a2[j]], {i, 51}, {j, 50}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.930523, Null}

```
counts == pos == a3
```

> True

Can't beat kglr's solution, though. It takes `0.41 s`.

Comment: nice work with `PositionIndex`. +1

Answer (score 5):

[`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) is optimized to work on packed arrays.  Let's try it.  As a self-contained function:

```
fn[x_, y_] :=
 Module[{a, b, m, n, toRow},
   {m, n} = Max /@ {x, y};
   {a, b} = Flatten /@ {x, y};
   toRow = SparseArray[Normal @ KeyDrop[0] @ Counts @ #, {n}] &;
   Array[toRow @ Pick[b, a, #] &, m]
 ]
```

Output matches kglr's:

```
img1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKpri.png"];
img2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzvfv.png"];

{seg1, seg2} = segmentImage /@ {img1, img2};

fn[seg1, seg2] == counts  (* True *)
```

Performance is superior by more than an order of magnitude:

```
fn[seg1, seg2] // RepeatedTiming // First

Normal[SparseArray[
    SparseArray[#, {50}] &@
       DeleteCases[Normal[Counts[Flatten[(1 - Unitize[seg1 - #]) seg2]]], 
        0 -> _] & /@ Range[51]]] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.026
>
> 0.488
> ```

---

The code above still scans the data fifty times.  That's [usually a bad idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25591/121).  With more segments this might become an issue.  As an attempt to avoid the problem I'll use Szabolcs's function from [How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/121) (as `pos`) as a substitute for `Pick`:

```
fn2[x_, y_] :=
  Module[{a, b, n, pos, toRow},
    n = Max[y];
    {a, b} = Flatten /@ {x, y};
    pos[lst_] := GatherBy[Range @ Length @ lst, lst[[#]] &];
    toRow = SparseArray[Normal @ KeyDrop[0] @ Counts @ #, {n}] &;
    toRow @ b[[#]] & /@ Rest @ pos @ a
  ]
```

Test:

```
fn[seg1, seg2] == fn2[seg1, seg2]

fn2[seg1, seg2] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> True
>
> 0.024
> ```

Only a slight edge over `fn` here but I expect it to pull ahead as the number of segments rises.

Comment: This is still about 3-4 times slower than my method. Also, I would pull the definition of `pos` outside of `fn2`, as there is no reason to define `pos` every time you run `fn2`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this is great ! +1

Comment: @CarlWoll That's weird, I completely overlooked your post.  Sorry!  I agree about externalizing `pos` but I wanted self-contained functions for the sake of this post.

Answer (score 4):

OK, as a learning exercise in associations I worked through this, and ended up with a faster result than the @kglr one. Count me surprised!

```
RepeatedTiming[
  cr = {seg1 // Flatten, seg2 // Flatten} // Transpose // Counts; 
  sa = SparseArray[ KeySelect[cr, FreeQ[0]] // Normal] // Normal;
]

(* out[11]={0.153, Null} *)
```

@kglr's

```
AbsoluteTiming[counts = Normal[SparseArray[SparseArray[#, {50}] &@DeleteCases[
   Normal[Counts[Flatten[(1 - Unitize[seg1 - #]) seg2]]], 0 -> _] & /@ Range[51]]];]

(* out[11]={0.478285, Null} *)
```

The matrices match (minus the fact that I did not pad the `sa`  matrix... the last row is all zeros)

```
sa == Counts // Most
(* true *)
```

Comment: Nice method.  I believe I can make your code cleaner while retaining the same performance and output by using `KeySelect`.  May I edit your post?

Comment: You bet, it was my first foray into Key[ ] type functions. I tried to use KeySelect[ ], but struggled with keys that are lists.

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: Nice simplification, thanks!

Comment: @MikeY +1 for your fast approach

Answer (score 1):

This approach works for the posted question as well as for cases when there are gaps in labels. What i mean by gaps is that the first or the second segmented mask may have a structure as follows: {1,2,3 ... 10,13,14,20} (11,12 as well as 16-19 are the missing labels).

```
overlapMatrix[seg1_,seg2_]:=Block[{keys1,keys2,mask,map,rules1,rules2},
keys1 = Keys@ComponentMeasurements[seg1, "Label"];
keys2 = Keys@ComponentMeasurements[seg2, "Label"];
mask= Unitize[seg1*seg2];
map = Normal@Counts@Thread[{SparseArray[mask*seg1]["NonzeroValues"],SparseArray[mask*seg2]["NonzeroValues"]}];
{rules1,rules2}= Dispatch@Thread[# -> Range@Length@#]&/@{keys1,keys2};
map[[All,1,1]]=map[[All,1,1]]/.rules1;
map[[All,1,2]]=map[[All,1,2]]/.rules2;
Normal@SparseArray[map,{Length@keys1,Length@keys2}]
];
```

Applying it over the above images

`overlapMatrix[seg1,seg2]`

`(* {0.167852, Null} *)`

Answer (score 0):

`Transpose` accepts a second parameter, which you can use to shuffle the values around a bit. I have used it to merge the value of the two arrays together in a list.

```
Normal[SparseArray[
   DeleteCases[Normal[
       Counts[Flatten[Transpose[{seg1, seg2}, {3, 2, 1}], {1, 2}]]],
       Rule[{0,0}|{0,_}|{_,0}, _]
   ], 
   {Max[seg1], Max[seg2]} 
]]
```