# Fastest way to check for list membership

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of say `100` numbers `{1,3,7,11,19,...3971}`. All elements are previously determined. I want to check whether `376` belongs to this set or not. what is the fastest way?
Thanks

Comment: `MemberQ[listOfElements,376]`

Answer (score 27):

As [andre](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5467/andre) notes this can be done simply with [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MemberQ.html).  However, the set you show is ordered, so other methods may be faster.  It probably won't matter for a set of "say 100 numbers" but it can make a big difference in longer sets.

Starting with a set of ordered unique elements:

```
set = Union @ RandomInteger[1*^7, 1*^6];
```

Timing using `MemberQ`:

```
Do[MemberQ[set, i], {i, 1, 1*^7, 77777}] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 5.834
> ```

Timing using `BinarySearch` from the Combinatorica package:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

Do[IntegerQ @ BinarySearch[set, i], {i, 1, 1*^7, 77777}] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.015
> ```

Also, if you are going to perform this test repeatedly, or if the set is not ordered, it is worth building a hash table:

```
rls = Dispatch @ Append[Thread[set -> True], _ -> False];
```

Now with a denser sampling:

```
Do[IntegerQ @ BinarySearch[set, i], {i, 1, 1*^7, 500}] // Timing // First

Do[Replace[i, rls], {i, 1, 1*^7, 500}] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.748
>
> 0.015
> ```

Of course if you can test them all at once it's even better (note very dense sampling):

```
Do[Replace[i, rls], {i, 1, 1*^7, 15}] // Timing // First

Replace[Range[1, 1*^7, 15], rls, {1}] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.671
>
> 0.39
> ```

Now, if all your elements are machine-size positive integers we can take this farther by building an array, then extracting values with `Part`:

```
 sa = SparseArray[Partition[set, 1] -> True, 1*^7, False];

 sa[[ Range[1, 1*^7, 15] ]] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.0268
> ```

This is about 1.1 *million* times faster than `MemberQ` on this set.  This requires that each of the test elements is within the set or you will get `Part:partw` error messages.  You could however `Clip` the input, setting out-of-bounds values to a known-`False` position.  There is overhead (~0.34 second) in building the `SparseArray` but once that is complete element tests are very fast.

Comment: You need to add `IntegerQ` to the output of `BinarySearch` to get a Boolean result.

Comment: @rm-rf Right -- corrected.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just love it when a Q turns into a benchmarking competition :D +1

Comment: @Sektor I'm glad you appreciate [my philosophy](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277/121). :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The sparse array approach is fast, but you're making an implicit assumption that all the keys being searched are less than the max value in the list. If the integer being checked is larger, then Part will complain. Of course, you can rectify this with a check, but that will probably also kill all the speed gains and perhaps make it slower than the rest of the approaches.

Comment: @rm-rf True, and I should have stated this.  One could `Clip` outliers to a known-`False` position to handle it efficiently I think, but I've spent enough time on this problem now.  Also, one could consider a non-sparse array or even a bitmask as alternatives... I'll leave those to someone else.

Comment: I'm trying to apply the SparseArray method. Apprently, under Matheamatica v10.0.2, your code for creating the SparseArray, returns now a SparseArray with `Length@set` dimensions. A `Thread[set->True]` is necessary, in some way according to the actual documentation. I'm not sure if it's an implementation bug, a documentation bug, a previous-version solved bug...

Comment: @unlikely Apparently this code didn't work in version 7 either so I made a mistake that no one called me on until you!  Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be nice to note here that `MemberQ` unpacks and that it can easily be compiled. I suppose reference to [Leonids compiled function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2371/4330) would also be nice (somehow I couldn't easily get it to work).

Comment: @Jacob Do you wish to post that yourself?

Comment: @Jacob The reason I did not sue Leonid's code is that as written it does not work as I want as one cannot directly tell from the result if an element is present or not.

Answer (score 21):

If you're going to do several lookups repeatedly in a single set, using [`Associations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) in version 10 is orders of magnitude faster than `BinarySearch`. You can try it out if you have *Mathematica* 10 for Raspberry Pi (publicly available) or the pre-release version.

```
set = Union @ RandomInteger[1*^7, 1*^6];
assoc = <|Thread[set -> True]|>; (* One time operation *)
Do[Lookup[assoc, i, False], {i, 1, 1*^7, 77777}] // Timing // First
(* 0.000152 *)
```

Here's the timings for `BinarySearch` on my computer:

```
Do[IntegerQ@BinarySearch[set, i], {i, 1, 1*^7, 77777}] // Timing // First
(* 0.016991 *)
```

which is about 100 times slower!

Comment: I was about to add a `Dispatch` table method to my answer, but that kind of took the wind out of my sails.  I suppose I still should for pre-v10 users.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, `Dispatch` should still be useful. `Association` is basically `Dispatch` on steroids

Comment: Do you know how the implementations (low level) differ?  How is the performance in a direct comparison?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard On my machine, `Association` is about twice as fast as `Dispatch`. I believe one of the developers mentioned somewhere that `Association` is highly optimized and implemented at a low level in the kernel, but I'm not privy to the details. `Association` serves the (much needed) role of key-value pair/dictionary, for which we were using rules up until now.

Comment: I notice that you did not use the `<|   |>` syntax here; a matter of clarity, preference, or need?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Association` being very new, the `<||>` syntax doesn't come naturally yet... :) I've updated the post.

Comment: It sure is a lot cleaner than `Dispatch` that way!  I added a new method to my answer, racing toward ultimate speed.  (And I hope other v10/Pi users come by and vote for this answer soon.)

Comment: +1. Out of curiosity, are these timings on your Raspberry Pi? If so what is the processor speed?

Comment: @RunnyKine My "Raspberry Pi" has a quad core 2.6 GHz i7 processor with 16 GB memory ;)

Comment: @RunnyKine I benchmarked this on my Raspberry Pi and these are the results: For a set with 10^7 elements the Pi runs out of memory. So I reduced it to 10^6 elements. `BinarySearch` takes about the same time as `Lookup` (0.002725 and 0.003627 seconds, respectively), but the initial `Association` takes 21 seconds, so it's slower in most cases.

Comment: You can easily `Compile` binary search, to get competitive performance (I've done that many times). You can also construct a massive compiled binary search, which I believe can be even quite a bit faster. But of course, +1.

Comment: @rm-rf The main advantages of `Association` w.r.t. say `DownValues` - based hash - table, apart from speed,  are that it is stateless / immutable and cheap to copy.  This allows `Association` to play well with the core Mathematica constructs. OTOH, it has also advantages over `Dispatch`, since you can add new or update old key-value pairs in constant time, getting a new `Association` - while `Dispatch` you can't efficiently update once it is formed.

Comment: @shrx. Thanks for the info. Interesting stuff.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Please see comments above by Leonid. Thanks, @Leonid! :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is some time comparition between `Dispatch` and `Association`, creating a `memberQFunction` using @rm-rf and @Mr.Wizard solutions.

```
memberQFunction1[set_]:=Module[{f,ass},
    ass=<|Thread[set -> True]|>;
    f[x_]:=Lookup[ass,x,False];
    f
]

memberQFunction2[set_]:=Module[{f,rule},
    rule=Dispatch@Append[Thread[set->True],_-> False];
    f[x_]:=x/.rule;
    f
]

memberQFunction3[set_]:=Module[{f,rule},
    rule=Dispatch@Map[#->True&,set];
    f[x_]:=If[x/.rule,True,False,False];
    f
]
```

Now let's create our hashed functions:

```
set = DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[1000000, 1000000]];
setSample = RandomSample[set, 100000];

mQ1 = memberQFunction1[set];
mQ2 = memberQFunction2[set];
mQ3 = memberQFunction3[set];
```

Testing it we get:

```
mQ1 /@ setSample // AbsoluteTiming // First
mQ2 /@ setSample // AbsoluteTiming // First
mQ3 /@ setSample // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.156000 (*Association*)
> 0.202800 (*Dispatch1*)
> 0.218400 (*Dispatch2*)
> ```

**Association wins!**

I hopped that the new [MemberQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html) operator form would be Hashed, just like `Nearest` does, creating a `NearestFunction`, but it's not the case, so `memberQFunction` (with `Association`) is a good alternative.

Answer (score 3):

V 12.1 introduced `CreateDataStructure`:

A link to its many members: [DataStructures](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataStructures.html)

A suitable choice for the question at hand would be [SortedMultiset](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/datastructure/SortedMultiset.html)

**1. Structure**

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["SortedMultiset"];

Scan[ds["Insert", #] &, Range @ 10]

ds["Elements"]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

```
ds["Visualization"]
```

[image]

**2. Timings**

```
list = Union @ RandomInteger[1*^7, 1*^6];

ds = CreateDataStructure["SortedMultiset"];

Scan[ds["Insert", #] &, list] // Timing // First
```

5.7673

Once inserted, access to its elements is ultra-fast:

```
Do[ds["MemberQ", i], {i, 1, 1*^7, 77777}] // Timing // First
```

0.00152

Compare to "normal" `MemberQ`:

```
Do[MemberQ[list, i], {i, 1, 1*^7, 77777}] // Timing // First
```

4.74134

Comment: Interesting. But you will need quite many queries to ammortize the huge insertion time of the tree. And I doubt that it will ever be more efficient than a `Sort` combined with a binary search, at least for simple data types.

Comment: `Scan[ds["Insert", #] &, list]` must have an enormous calling overhead. One can try to build the tree also with `CreateDataStructure["SortedMultiset", list]`. I had hoped that it would improve the timings, but it barely did so. Which tells me that the data structure is badly designed. I guess this constructor is not implemented on the C/C++ side of the backend.

Comment: But you might also consider that a SINGLE `MemberQ`-Query takes 4.74 seconds. Doesn't amortization come soon enough? On the other hand I agree that a compiled binary search would be more efficient, but not everybody has the expertise to write such code.

Comment: `nf = Nearest[list];found = Flatten[nf[Range[1, 1*^7, 7777], {1, 0}]];` might be a good compromise between built time and lookup time. It outputs all the elements found and not the boolean flags. But that can easily be converted.