# Handling lists indexed with integer partitions

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, associations, data-structures, benchmarking

I am trying to do some exploration around the multi-dimensional version of [truncated moment problem], where I work with various distributions (uni- or multi-variate), and use some truncated moment sequences of them. I frequently use three different types of sequences:

- when the distribution is a fully independent joint, the truncated sequence is represented as a $K\times \tau$ matrix,
  where $K$ is the valence of the distribution and $\tau$ is the truncation to the order of moments;
  from this matrix desired joint moments can be readily computed.
- when the distribution is correlated:

  - independent truncations $\tau_k$ for each variate $x_k$: the truncated sequence is represented as a $\tau_1\times\tau_2\times\cdots\times\tau_K$-dimensional array
  - one overall truncation $\tau$: sometimes I need all the joint moments whose order is $\leqslant\tau$; if I use the previous scheme, I would have to save a $\tau^K$-dimensional array, where the majority of entries are not used.

Therefore, I am trying to find out which construct I should use to represent the third kind of truncated  sequence. The options that I currently know of are:

1. a ragged array (a nested `List` in which each sublist is of different length)
2. an association (hash map) where I use [multi-indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation) (`List`s with integer entries) as keys.

Which has the better performance? Is there better ways to handle such arrays?

---

**Update**  I find a [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22327/72025) at MMA SE; the accepted answer suggests using a [dispatch table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html), but as associations are introduced, won't (speaking for this case only) replacing dispatch tables with associations avoid invoking the pattern-matching mechanism and make things faster?

Theoretically, with some optimised byte alignment, float-valued integer-partition (from now on I'll call them `intpart` for short) indexed arrays can be represented compactly in the memory; these however may be slow to access, and will definitely be hard to mutate. A hash map is a more flexible alternative. The real problem is which Wolfram built-in hashes the way best suited for this case (for the lack of better phrasing). Compared to `Dispatch` and `Association`, is using compiled ragged lists a good idea?

Comment: (1) Ragged arrays do not at this time have reasonable support from `Compile`. This may change as the new compiler matures. `Dispatch` and `Association` are likely to be roughly equivalent in speed, and the only way to know which is better is to run timing tests. Both will use hashing under the hood, and I suspect they use the same (or at least similar) hashing schemes (your phrasing was quite clear, by the way).

Comment: (2) This is related to handling of multivariate Maclaurin/Taylor expansions, wherein one wants to expand to a given total degree. Depending oin what exactly you require in terms of data to store, you might find some reasonable ideas by searching MSE for threads on that topic.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks a lot for your suggestion, this is really helpful. Searching for these posts will take some time, and I'll be back at this post later. I have made some test on the built-in [SeriesData](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html); it basically uses a verbose ragged array, though. After all, it is designed for symbolic computation and display and compactness is not its goal. So this is a dead end. :D

Comment: The multivariate case constrained by total degree actually is done as a univariate expansion. Whether the result can be adapted to your specific needs is another question though.